# How to get real path from URI

Tags: java, android, path, uri

I know that there is a function to get the real path from URI:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

My problem is, that managedQuery can´t be found.

I also found this solution:

```
ebild = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + "filename.jpg"
```

but I don´t know how to get "filename.jpg". 
The only thing I have is the URI in the format

```
/external/images/media/10146
```

and I need it like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1368438768752.jpg
```

How can I convert the URI in the right format?

Comment: that's (/external/images/media/10146) what getRealPathFromURI is returning?

Comment: contentUri.getPath() should return to you the file system path

Comment: No, this link is returned when I add an image to the galery with the camera intent.

Comment: is there no solution?

Comment: When you say that managedQuery can't be found - do you mean that you're unable to compile the code? If so - note that it's a method of an activity. see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935497/android-uploading-image. hope it'll help.