# How can you load image string paths and image files with picasso and glide?

Tags: android, uri, picasso, android-glide, android-photos

So no matter what I do, neither picasso and glide can load an image File OR an image string path into an imageview.

I've tried.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};//Array size of 1, and we put in a string
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            user_image_path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);//here we have our image path.
            cursor.close();

            File tempFile2 = new File(selectedImage.getPath());

            //Toast.makeText(this, "I got your image " + user_image_path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraActivity_ImageView);
            //Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);
            Glide.with(this).load(new File(selectedImage.getPath())).centerCrop().into(myImageView);


        }



    }
```

So I've tried:

1)`Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(user_image_path).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

2)`Glide.with(this).load(user_image_path).centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

3)`Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(tempFile2).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

4)`Glide.with(this).load(tempFile2).centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

5)`Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage.getPath())).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

6)`Glide.with(this).load(selectedImage.getPath())).centerCrop().into(myImageView);`

None of them worked. If i use the:

```
Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);

Glide.with(this).load(selectedImage).centerCrop().into(myImageView);
```

These two above work with the Uri selectedImage variable, but none of the others work. So why aren't the other options working and how do I get them to work, because ideally I want to work with image path Strings.

Hope you guys can help! im totally stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(data.getData()).into(imageView);
```

Comment: That didn't work, and it kept saying "wrap uri with String.valueOf()"

Comment: Try this Picasso.with(context).load(data.getData()).into(imageView);

Comment: yeah the data.getData() works, but its the same as:

Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);

I want to know how to use a string path or File object with Picasso or glide

Answer (score 0):

Glide can do via Uri, as the code mention below. **But you should check**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

if you already done it, I have no idea.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode  == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == PIC_REQ_CODE){
            Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_result));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah the data.getData() works, but its the same as:

Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);

I want to know how to use a string path or File object with Picasso or glide

Comment: Glide can use uri directly but picasso cannot. If you want to change uri to actual part please read this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935497/android-uploading-image