# How can I transform a Bitmap into a Uri?

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I'm trying to share images with Facebook, twitter, etc using `SHARE INTENT` from Android.

I found code to send a image to the share intent, but this code needs the URI of the bitmap: `fullSizeImageUri`

This is the full code:

```
private void startShareMediaActivity(Bitmap image) {
    boolean isVideo=false;
    String mimeType="bmp";
    Uri fullSizeImageUri=null;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fullSizeImageUri);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, (isVideo ? "video" : "image")));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) { }
}
```

How to transform a Bitmap into a Uri?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
String FILENAME = "image.png";
String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/"+ FILENAME;
File f = new File(PATH);
Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
```

Comment: Parse always take as argument a String not a file. Next time read details about functions or maybe test them.

Comment: can't we get Uri without saving the bitmap

Comment: work in android studio 2022 bumblebee

Comment: @rezarahmad Dear sheldon, This was answered 10 years back,

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 yes this still working until 2023 and more future years

Answer (score 94):

Here is the Colin's Blog who suggest the simple method to convert bitmap to Uri [Click here](http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/android-getting-image-uri-from-bitmap/)

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: Note this creates an image that will stick around in the users gallery.

Comment: path can be null, if so, Uri.parse(path) will make app crash

Comment: Dont forget to take WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Otherwise 
insertImage method may return null.

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283353/3341089

Comment: @Noman If you want to delete inserted image, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511111/3341089

Comment: Not workking in android oreo, 
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
path will get null.

Comment: The background of my image became black. How to make the background transparent?

Comment: This method is deprecated

Comment: @MrinmoyMk did you figured out how to get rid of that black background?

Comment: @Ajay you're a boss

Answer (score 6):

The latest solution I found is this. Its in kotlin you can covert it in Java.

```
    // Get uri of images from camera function
private fun getImageUri(inContext: Context?, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {

    val tempFile = File.createTempFile("temprentpk", ".png")
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes)
    val bitmapData = bytes.toByteArray()

    val fileOutPut = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
    fileOutPut.write(bitmapData)
    fileOutPut.flush()
    fileOutPut.close()
    return Uri.fromFile(tempFile)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The above solution uses media store and stores the image in the users main image folder making it viewable through the gallery/photo viewer.  This solution will store it as a temporary file in your apps data. In this example inImage is a Bitmap and title is a string for the name of the image file.

```
    File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/");
    tempDir.mkdir();
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(title, ".jpg", tempDir);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    byte[] bitmapData = bytes.toByteArray();

    //write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    fos.write(bitmapData);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    return Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
```

Comment: How temporary is temporary?
When will the file be deleted? Can I use the same file name for several images in quick succession?

Comment: instead of tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/"); you can always use a directory exclusively used by your app.. and just leave the images there

Comment: @Joel Also if you are using in a loop name the file name as "file"+i and on success of your process like an api response you can clear this folder -> that will have to be done manually

Answer (score 2):

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val uri = context.saveImage(bitmap) // here you will receive the Uri


private fun Context.saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap): Uri? {
    var uri: Uri? = null
    try {
        val fileName = System.nanoTime().toString() + ".png"
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
            } else {
                val directory =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                val file = File(directory, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.absolutePath)
            }
        }

        uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        uri?.let {
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(it).use { output ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output)
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                values.apply {
                    clear()
                    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                }
                contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
            }
        }
        return uri
    }catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        if (uri != null) {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
        }
        throw e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pass bitmap and compressFormat like (PNG, JPG, etc...) and image quality in percentage

```
public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap src, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    src.compress(format, quality, os);

    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), src, "title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: path can be null, so your code would crash on Uri.parse(path)

Comment: you check path is null or not. and after you pass in Uri

Comment: @PankajTalaviya This method is saving the image with .jpg format even we provide PNG format to compress.

Comment: @PankajMundra Increase decrease quality percentage to compress image

Comment: So according to you what should be the appropriate percentage to save image as .png...because if it saves as jpeg the background of image is black.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't transforma a bitmap file into a uri. Read more about URI [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)

URI is an Uniform Resource Identifier. But you can place the bitmap in an absolute or relative URI like this

```
Absolute: http://android.com/yourImage.bmp
Relative: yourImage.bmp
```

Comment: then how can achieve my needs? it's impossible?

Comment: I guess you have to rethink your way to see this... check Facebook and twitter APIS to see how you can achieve that image sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
String picName = "pic.jpg";
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ picName;
        File f = new File(PATH);
        Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
```