# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage returns null in some devices

Tags: java, android, mediastore

Possibly Duplicate but did not find any solution.

I am trying to modify image and saving it to device using `MediaStore`. with following code -:

```
public class Utils {

    private Utils() {

    }

    static Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null); //returning null in some devices
        Log.d("TAG", "getUri: "+path);
        return Uri.parse(path);   //this is returning null which cause the app crash
    }

    static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
        return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
    }
}
```

This code is working well in most of devices but the problem is that `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` returning null in some devices like -:

**1**. Samsung J7(2016)

**2**. LG Magna LTE

**3**. Android Emulator API 21

I am surprised this app is working in **Android Emulator API 26** . but getting crashed on **Android Emulator API 21**

I have searched google and I have also find the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906370/mediastore-images-media-insertimage-return-null-sometimes) but not find any sufficient answer.

**NOTE - :** I have used Runtime Permission for **Read/Write External Storage**

But still getting crash in mentioned devices. Below is my crash log-:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:51 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example/com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
       at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:470)
       at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:460)
       at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:432)
       at com.scanlibrary.Utils.getUri(Utils.java:24)
       at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.postImagePick(PickImageFragment.java:228)
       at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.onActivityResult(PickImageFragment.java:208)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6196)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `compress()` on `Bitmap` to write the image to a `FileOutputStream` on a file of your choosing. Index that with the `MediaScannerConnection`. As a bonus feature, you now know where the image is being stored and can choose a place that the user might appreciate. Your current code stores the image in a location that neither you nor the user chooses.

Comment: I agree @CommonsWare that a good solution to save files or I am also saving pdf file using `FileOutputStream` to a specific place in my app. But I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: Apparently, the image failed to be stored. Check LogCat for messages (e.g., `"Failed to insert image"`, `"Failed to create thumbnail, removing original"`) in the `MediaStore` tag.

Comment: No @CommonsWare i don't have any messages in LogCat like you have mention in your comment. You can see my LogCat above in my question

Comment: From what I saw in the source code, any scenario in which you would get a `null` result should log a message.

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare I am logging the result and the log print `null` when i am testing in mentioned devices.

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056101/12272687

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using below code-:

```
String path = MediaStore.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),bitmap,"Title",null);
```

Use this code(below)-:

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"Title");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"From Camera");
Uri path=getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

pass values as null if it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jithesh this works with fine for saving image to data base but when i am `gettingBitmap` from the same `uri` then I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Whatever above code i added that is properly works for capture image from camera.

Comment: @Jitheshkumar, Where you are putting or adding bitmap with this above code to insert???

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {

if (requestCode == RequestPermissionCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        try {

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null)
                return;
            // find the file in the media area
            cursor.moveToLast();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = "file:///"+cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            actualImage = FileUtil.from(this,Uri.parse(filePath));
            actualImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(actualImage.getAbsolutePath()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Use onActvittyResult method i hope it will work.