# Should we still use MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() method?

Tags: android, mediastore

I see a lot of discussions about saving images to gallery in android and I was wondering if the MediaStore was still a good way of proceeding ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never recommended that approach, for one simple reason: you have no idea where that image winds up.

Instead, save the image to some known, controllable location, then use `MediaScannerConnection` to let the `MediaStore` know about that image. Bonus points if you let the user control the location, with your app simply providing a default location for users who do not configure it separately.

Answer (score 3):

Using `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(...)` you will end up with two files. Here's how to do what CommonsWare suggested:

```
// ...
// (save your image as usual to your custom location)
// ...

// notify mediascanner of the new image
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                            new String[] { yourFilePath }, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As this method  `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` is **deprecated** , it's better use a new method such as:

```
val mDrawable: Drawable? = baseContext.getDrawable(id)
val mbitmap = (mDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
val mfile = File(externalCacheDir, "myimage.PNG")
        try {
            val outStream = FileOutputStream(mfile)
            mbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream)
            outStream.flush()
            outStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
```