# can not use MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have a project up and running on the store, and suddenly clients start to complain about not able to capture images using my app although I did not make any changes in this part I just update android and make a new build for issue does not related to capture image

This is my code

```
@Override
        public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, Bitmap bitmap) {
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, getPhotoFilename(), null);

            if(path == null) {
                final Activity activity = getActivity();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.photo_save_error_toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTakePictureBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(path);
                final Image image = getImageFromContentUri(contentUri);

                // run the media scanner service
                // MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{path}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, contentUri));

                // the current method is an async. call.
                // so make changes to the UI on the main thread.
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((ImagePickerActivity) getActivity()).addImage(image);
                        mTakePictureBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

the error that happen in the background is as following

```
Failed to insert image
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=5494, uid=10570 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1280)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:1025)
        at nl.changer.polypicker.CwacCameraFragment$DemoCameraHost.saveImage(CwacCameraFragment.java:172)
        at nl.changer.polypicker.camera.ImageCleanupTask.run(ImageCleanupTask.java:136)
```

of-course I have requested the **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, **CAMERA**  in my app in manifest and also in runtime permission and user accept in the dialog, but still give that error

can anyone help please ?

**EDIT**

```
if (PermissionManager.getInstance().hasSelfPermissions(getActivity(), PermissionManager.getInstance().getCameraAndStoragePermissions()) == false) {

            mImageAndVideoParentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PermissionManager.getInstance().checkForCameraAndStoragePermissions2((Fragment) this, PermissionManager.CAMERA_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {

            mImageAndVideoParentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
------------------------
public boolean hasSelfPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (!hasSelfPermission(context, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
-----------------------
public String[] getCameraAndStoragePermissions() {
        return mCameraAndStoragePermissions;
    }
-------------------------------
private String [] mCameraAndStoragePermissions = {

            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

---------------------------
public void checkForCameraAndStoragePermissions2(Fragment fragment, int requestCode) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            fragment.requestPermissions(mCameraAndStoragePermissions, requestCode);

        } else {
            Log.i("AMIRA", "Below M, permissions not via code");
        }
    }
--------------------------
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.i("AMIRA", "PostAdFragment : onRequestPermissionsResult " + requestCode);

        if (requestCode == PermissionManager.LOCATION_PERMISSIONS) {
            initalizeMap();
        } else if (requestCode == PermissionManager.CAMERA_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS) {
            mImageAndVideoParentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056101/12272687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you handled what happens when the user Denies the permission or clicks Don't show again? You should disable the functionalities when the permission is disabled or prompt again and again till the permission is given.

EDIT:

Android now limits the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with the maxSdkVersion filter. In some use cases, e.g. where an app contains a dependency that requires this permission, maxSdkVersion makes it impossible for those dependencies to grant or request the permission. The solution for those cases is to declare the tools:node="replace" manifest merging strategy later in the dependency tree:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

Comment: yes I handled it, the problem happen even if the user press allow

Comment: what is your target api?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 25, and I know that play store will stop in in November and only allow 26, but I have to keep it until I update one of the third libraries

Comment: share your request permissions code and onRequestPermissionResult code please

Comment: did you find anything in the code that may cause this problem ?

Comment: please check in your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> check that it's android.permission

Comment: also try this grantUriPermission(null, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: I have already add permission in manifest + I have used grant permission and still did not work

Comment: I have also tried to downgrade the target sdk to 22, and it did not work also

Comment: Share it to github. Will check it

Comment: there is no problem in the code, what I found that 

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE grant result is always -1 , even if the user press allow

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>

Comment: it works, Thank you very much, can you please explain to me what was the problem ?