# java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString [share image ]

Tags: android, share, android-glide

I'm trying to add share feature to my app I tried this code and it's work fine on Android 5.0 and Android 7.0 but when I run my app on Android 6.0.1 I get this error

> Process: maa.myapp, PID: 20195
>                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>                                                                                at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:476)
>                                                                                at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:466)
>                                                                                at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:438)
>                                                                                at maa.myapp.full$2$2.onResourceReady(full.java:122)
>                                                                                at maa.myapp.full$2$2.onResourceReady(full.java:118)

Here is my code:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<?super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), resource,"title", null);
                            Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("image/png");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
                            lt.success();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Is either `bitmapPath` or `resource` null when running on Android 6.0.1?

Comment: @Maxwell i get the error in `Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);` so i think is `bitmapPath`

Comment: Does this answer provide any useful insight? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422186/1102687

Comment: Or perhaps this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283353/1102687 
This seems to be more related to your situation since it's dealing with 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Comment: @Maxwell thanks so much I followed this tutorial [Android Tutorial: Photo app – Save bitmap to SD card or Share via Intent](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-photo-app-save-bitmap-to-sd-card-or-share-via-intent/) Where he saved the image first and then share it