# Take picture and convert to Base64

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, android-camera

I use code below to make a picture with camera. Instead of saving I would like to encode it to `Base64` and after that pass it to another API as an input. I can't see method, how to modify code to take pictures in `Base64` instead of regular files.

```
public class CameraDemoActivity extends Activity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();

        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newfile.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }

                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use code below to convert an image to `Base64`.

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Above described should be a much more direct and easier way than saving image and after that looking for image to encode it.

Comment: `I try to use code below to convert an image to Base64`. No that code is for converting a Bitmap to base64. And you have a .jpg file. No bitmap.

Comment: `newfile.createNewFile();`. Remove that. The Camera app will create the file.

Comment: `take pictures in Base64 instead of regular files`. ?? One cannot compare base64 with a file.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:
 **ImageUri to Bitmap:**

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                String encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
            }
        }
```

**Encode Bitmap in base64**

```
   private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encImage;
    }
```

**Encode from FilePath to base64**

```
 private String encodeImage(String path)
    {
        File imagefile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //Base64.de
        return encImage;

    }
```

output:
[image]

Comment: This code makes a bitmap from a jpg file. Then the bitmap is concerted to jpg again. Finally the jpg is base64 encoded. Better omit the bitmap. Just base64 encode the .jpg file directly.

Comment: Moreover there is still a file saved by the camera app. OP asked for something without a file.

Comment: But first of all, I cannot see the file. I am using TC for searching it, but it is nowhere.

Comment: How do you go back, String to Bitmap or Uri?

Comment: i convert this code on kotlin but this not working now .

Answer (score 3):

I've wrote my code like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.startPreview();// I don't know why I added that, 
                               // but without it doesn't work... :D

        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            System.out.println("***************");
            System.out.println(Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT));
            System.out.println("***************");
        }
    };
}
```

It works perfectly...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for converting from bitmap to base64 string in kotlin I use:

```
private fun encodeImage(bm: Bitmap): String? {
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val b = baos.toByteArray()
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your base64 String  to follow the standard format, add this after getting your base64 method from any of the provided answers

```
String base64 =""; //Your encoded string
base64 = "data:image/"+getMimeType(context,profileUri)+";base64,"+base64;
```

The method to get imageExtension is

```
   public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String extension;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            //If scheme is a content
            final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        } else {
            //If scheme is a File
            //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
            extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());
        }
        return extension;
    }
```

Comment: what is `profileUri`? where is defined?!!

Comment: profileUri is the uri of your bitmap. You can check this answer on how to get uri from bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168087/11118152

Answer (score 1):

```html
  try {
                    val imageStream: InputStream? = requireActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mProfileUri)
                    val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
                    val b = baos.toByteArray()
                    val encodedString: String = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT)

                    Log.d("check string" ,encodedString.toString())

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

For kotlin use code is given bellow just copy this and give image uri at "mProfileUri"
```