# How to convert Uri image into Base64?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have write code to convert image from file location into base64. I can easily convert image into base64 from absolute file location like: **C:/Users/Java Engineer/Desktop/test/gallery/magar/Kanuglam.jpg** , but I can not convert from location like
[image]
. I want to convert image to use in android from web-service.
Here is code sample :

```
/**
 * TEST JSON
 */
String convertToJsonArrayWithImageForMovieDetailTest(ResultSet rs) {

    System.out.println("I am insied json converter");
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj ;

    //File file;
    File locatedFile;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    try {

        while (rs.next()) {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            System.out.println("inside RS");
            System.out.println("date is there ha ha ");

            obj.put("movie_name", rs.getString("name"));
            obj.put("movie_gener", rs.getString("type"));
            String is_free_stuff = rs.getString("is_free_stuff");
            if (is_free_stuff == "no") {
                is_free_stuff = "PAID";
            } else {
                is_free_stuff = "FREE";
            }
            obj.put("movie_type", is_free_stuff);

            //String movie_image = rs.getString("preview_image");

            //this does not work
            String movie_image = "http://www.hamropan.com/stores/slider/2016-09-10-852311027.jpg";

            //this works for me
        //  file = new File("C:/Users/Java Engineer/Desktop/Nike Zoom Basketball.jpg");
            locatedFile = new File(movie_image);
            // Reading a Image file from file system
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(locatedFile);
            if (locatedFile == null) {
                obj.put("movie_image", "NULL");
            } else {
                byte[] iarray = new byte[(int) locatedFile.length()];
                fileInputStream.read(iarray);
                byte[] img64 = com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64
                        .encode(iarray);
                String imageString = new String(img64);
                obj.put("movie_image", imageString);
            }
            list.add(obj);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list.toString();
}
```

*this block of code works for me but it seem slow*

```
public String imageConvertMethod(String url) throws Exception{
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
             output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }

    byte [] byte_array = output.toByteArray();

    byte[] img64 = com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64
            .encode(byte_array);
    String  imageString = new String(img64);

    return imageString;
}
```

Comment: You have to download the file first.

Comment: Nonsense. And your post told something else.

Comment: what is saying from my post?  @greenapps

Comment: It works with this code but too slow . `public String lokConvertMethod(String url) throws Exception{
  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  try (InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream()) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
      for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
           output.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
  }
  
  byte [] byte_array = output.toByteArray();
  
  byte[] img64 = com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64
    .encode(byte_array);
  String  imageString = new String(img64);
  
  return imageString;
 }`

Comment: Shoul we read that? Post code in your post. Its unreadable now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this

```
bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(image_url);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

byte[] array = stream.getByteArray();
encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
```

Method wo load image from url

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
  try {
      URL url = new URL(src);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.connect();
      InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
      return myBitmap;
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to get image relative path like: /abc/cba/a.jpg and convert it into string and send it to android application. When i use c:/abc/cba/a.jpg it works , but /abc/cba/a.jpg don't work.I am using web-service(jersey api) which is located in D: dir but image is in C: so , I want to get image from my web-service app directory to another relative dir. I tried using Url BUT  it is too slow so need another option. thanks

Comment: thank you all friends who tried to help me , but i am compel to use another ideas , where , i'll save image in database as blob and get it to android app.

Answer (score 1):

@thanks to Fabio Venturi Pastor

Try this:

**ImageUri to Bitmap:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        String encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
    }
}
```

**Encode Bitmap in base64**

```
private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encImage;
}
```

**Encode from FilePath to base64**

```
private String encodeImage(String path)
{
    File imagefile = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    //Base64.de
    return encImage;

}
```

**output:**

[image]

reference :
[Take picture and convert to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189503/take-picture-and-convert-to-base64)