# How To Convert A Bitmap Image To Uri

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

I have not found the answer to this question anywhere.

The Bitmap Image is processed in The application, meaning there is no File path to get the Image.

Below is how to convert a Uri to Bitmap

```
 if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        imageview.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

        try {
            bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 7, bytearrayoutputstream);

        BYTE = bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray();

        bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE, 0, BYTE.length);

        imagetoo.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
    }
```

How do I now reconvert to a Uri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i transform a Bitmap into a Uri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295773/how-can-i-transform-a-bitmap-into-a-uri)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

URI is super set of URL that means its a path to file . whereas Bitmap  is a digital image composed of a matrix of dots.Bitmap represents a data and uri represents that location where data is saved .SO if you need to get a URI for a bitmap You just need to save it on a storage . In android you can do it by Java IO like below:First Create a file where you want to save it :

```
public File createImageFile() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File mFileTemp = null;
    String root=activity.getDir("my_sub_dir",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Img");
    if(!myDir.exists()){
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        mFileTemp=File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",myDir.getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mFileTemp;
}
```

Then flush it and you will get the URi

```
 File file = createImageFile(context);
 if (file != null) {
    FileOutputStream fout;
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        currentImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, fout);
        fout.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

This is just an example not idle code for all android version. To use `Uri` above and on android N  you should use [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve the file . Follow the Commonsware's answer.

Comment: good explanation. I had that idea, i din know how to put it out. Lemme try in a minute

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What is "activity" and "context" on "String root=activity.getDir..." and "File file = createImageFile(context);" respectively ?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`compress()` on `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to write the bitmap to a file. Then, most likely, [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve that file, where [`getUriForFile()` gives you the `Uri` corresponding to the file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)).

IOW, you do not "convert" a bitmap to a `Uri`. You save the bitmap somewhere that gives you a `Uri`.