# Get Uri from File or FilePath

Tags: android

I have file in this path:

```
file:/storage/emulated/0/iWallet/photos/JPEG_20180119040510_972640968.jpg
```

I want to convert it to `android.net.Uri` and use it in this:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoFile.toURI());
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_CAMIRA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "i have file in this path "file:/storage/emulated/0/iWallet/photos/JPEG_20180119040510_972640968.jpg"" -- that is not a path. `/storage/emulated/0/iWallet/photos/JPEG_20180119040510_972640968.jpg` is a path. On Android 7.0 and older, you can get away with using `Uri.fromFile()`. On newer devices, use `FileProvider` to serve up files from this location.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460710/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-image-to-uri

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare for your fast answer i selvet by check my FileProvider xml path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was with File Provider so i solve like that

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    DBConnect.FILEPROVIDER,
                    photoFile);

            URI uri = photoFile.toURI();


            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_CAMIRA);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/iWallet/photos/JPEG_20180119040510_972640968.jpg"))
```

Comment: This does not work for sdk >=24, you have to use file provider for the same.