# Convert from bitmap to uri

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I tried to convert bitmap to uri but the application crashes.

I tried many codes that posted here but none of them worked for me.

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Uri tempUri = getImageUri(this,photo);

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = 
     MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), 
     inImage, 
     "Title", null);
      return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

This is the error I get:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth, PID: 28469
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth/net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.UploadProductActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4496)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4538)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>           at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:490)
>           at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:480)
>           at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:452)
>           at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.UploadProductActivity.getImageUri(UploadProductActivity.java:404)
>           at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.UploadProductActivity.onActivityResult(UploadProductActivity.java:390)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4489)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4538) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
>   D/AbstractTracker: Event success
>   Process 28469 terminated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment since I'm also new here so I'll type this as an answer

Check this code out --> [BitmapIntoUri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295773/how-can-i-transform-a-bitmap-into-a-uri)