# Open stream from uri

Tags: java, uri

I got an uri (`java.net.URI`) such as http://www.example.com. How do I open it as a stream in Java?

Do I really have to use the URL class instead?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the URL class?

Comment: The problem with URL is that equals and hashcode are blocking operations which does network lookup. Url also seems to be missing a method to normalize a url and convert an relative url to an absolute url.

Comment: ["Use `URI` where possible" – Java Puzzlers Episode VI](https://youtu.be/wDN_EYUvUq0?t=9m58s).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will have to create a new `URL` object and then open stream on the `URL` instance. An example is below.

```
try {

   URL url = uri.toURL(); //get URL from your uri object
   InputStream stream = url.openStream();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: uri.toURL() is not showing in my android studio project?

Comment: same uri.toURL() is not showing in my android studio

Comment: `toURL()` does not work on Android because Android uses `android.net.Uri`, not `java.net.URI` as referenced in this post. For Android [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38568666/559745).

Answer (score 6):

`URLConnection connection = uri.toURL().openConnection()`

Yes, you have to use the [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) class in one way or the other.

Answer (score 5):

You should use ContentResolver to obtain InputStream:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Code is valid inside Activity object scope.

Answer (score 3):

`uri.toURL().openStream()` or `uri.toURL().openConnection().getInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URLConnection` to read data for given URL. - [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)