# Using a "virtual file" in Java

Tags: java, file, http

I have the following situation:
I'm writing an importer for the [GLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) format (3d graphics). It works fine as far as it is done and reads the data from the files into memory using `java.io.FileInputStream` and `java.io.File`.

Now I want to add that the gltf/glb files can be loaded from a Server (or other source that is not a local file) (e.g HTTP/FTP interface - possible even a Database).

Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to do this (thought about using `java.net.URI` after all URIs can point to [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) alltough I wouldn't know how to implement it in Java). I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595091/how-to-create-a-new-java-io-file-in-memory) question but considering it is from 2013 I figured I'd ask it anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657762/2478398
Does that work for your use case?

Comment: @BeUndead maybe. Altough I would need to figure out how to hook up something from a db would that still work ?