# How to get the Full file path from URI

Tags: android, path, get, uri

I'd like to get the full file path, from a URI. The URI isn't a Image, but it's a music file, but if i do it like the MediaStore Solution, it won't work if the app user selects eg Astro as browser, instead of Music Player. How do I solve this?

Comment: **I found the best one.** More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61995806/13877337

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use:

```
String path = yourAndroidURI.uri.getPath() // "/mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3"
File file = new File(new URI(path));
```

or

```
String path = yourAndroidURI.uri.toString() // "file:///mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3"
File file = new File(new URI(path));
```

Comment: The constructor File(URI) is undefined ?

Comment: @user3241507 I think that has something to do with the import settings of your app, try pressing ctrl+ O in eclipse, then all the required imports will be added, and all the unused will be removed

Comment: The result of Uri::getPath will start with "/", and the result of Uri::toString() will start with "file://" on my machine.

Comment: You also need to surround it with try/catch

Comment: This answer is actively harmful and does not deserve the votes it get. It fails if the Uri is a `content://` or any other non-file Uri.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Comment: I don't understand why this is still the accepted answer. It simply doesn't work nowadays.

Comment: What's that `yourAndroidURI` for?

Comment: it shows 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path'

Comment: `uri.toString()` gives me "content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fbackup.file", `uri.getPath()` gives me "/1/file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/backup.file" and `new File(uri.getPath())` gives me "/1/file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/backup.file". So answer is not fully correct

Answer (score 95):

The PathUtil method will be only working in below oreo and if it is oreo than it is likely to crash because in oreo we will not get the id but the entire path in data.getData() so all u need to do is create a file from uri and get its path from getPath() and split it.below is the working code:-

```
Uri uri = data.getData(); 
File file = new File(uri.getPath());//create path from uri
final String[] split = file.getPath().split(":");//split the path.
filePath = split[1];//assign it to a string(your choice).
```

The above code will work in oreo and if it is below oreo than PathUtil will work.Thanks!

```
String filePath=PathUtil.getPath(context,yourURI);
```

PathUtil.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.content.ContentUris; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Build; 
import android.os.Environment; 
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * Created by Aki on 1/7/2017.
 */

public class PathUtil {
    /*
     * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        // deal with different Uris.
        if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still gives me null.

Comment: @akhilesh0707  getPath() will return null for external sdcard files.Any solution for that??

Comment: I'm getting an error saying the filepath is null. The answer by Harsh Bhavsar using RealPathUtils works, but requires a bit more effort since you have to handle users using different Android versions.

Comment: This doesn't work with downloaded files on Android 9: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/18

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is depricated

Comment: None of the above suggested answers is working for me on Pie (Android 9) when tried to select pdf and get its path. :(

Comment: @NarendraSingh Can you please help me with this detailed and Bounty added question? It would be really appreciate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-after-nougat-using-retrofit

Comment: Could you get path from these URIs "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A80" (Documents) and "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A81" (Downloads)?

Answer (score 73):

one of the answers that exist on the current page ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri#answer-55469368)), is correct but it has some mistakes. for example, it won't work on devices with API 29+.
I'll update the above code and post its new version.
I think this post should be marked as the final answer.

You can download the code from my GitHub repo too:

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/saparkhid/AndroidFileNamePicker)

You can fork me to update the code.

Updated code: (**Added WhatsApp support**)

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileUtils {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;

    Context context;

    public FileUtils( Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath( final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat ) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider

           if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
                if (fullPath != "") {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }


            // DownloadsProvider

            if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    final String id;
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                        }
                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                        };
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            try {
                                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));


                                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
                else {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                }
            }


            // MediaProvider
           if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;

                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }

           if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri);
            }

           if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
            }


           if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

                if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();
                }
                if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                    return getDriveFilePath(uri);
                }
                if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                {

                    // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                    return copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"userfiles");
                    // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
                }
                else
                {
                    return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
                }

           }
           if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        }
        else {

            if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
            }

            if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                String[] projection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                };
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }




        return null;
    }

    private  boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        return file.exists();
    }

    private String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
        final String type = pathData[0];
        final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
        String fullPath = "";

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath;
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    /***
     * Used for Android Q+
     * @param uri
     * @param newDirName if you want to create a directory, you can set this variable
     * @return
     */
    private String copyFileToInternalStorage(Uri uri,String newDirName) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;

        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, new String[]{
                OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,OpenableColumns.SIZE
        }, null, null, null);


        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

        File output;
        if(!newDirName.equals("")) {
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name);
        }
        else{
            output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
        }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            int read = 0;
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        return output.getPath();
    }

    private String getFilePathForWhatsApp(Uri uri){
            return  copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"whatsapp");
    }

    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private  boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public boolean isWhatsAppFile(Uri uri){
        return "com.whatsapp.provider.media".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried this with the new google photos app? it's not working.

Comment: Consider posting it to Github as a library. I found it to be the most consistent from Android 4 to 10

Comment: This solution may cause problems in getting path for files from Sd card/ external storage in latest Api versions or for getting pdf or other file formats, please refer to this solution- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352140/12552434

Comment: in getDataColumn() func, uri is null. Same issue like PathUtils

Comment: Finally it's work by adding a case for "file:" provider

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid Hello a question on this, what happens if the document is pdf from documents folder,

Comment: @BRDroid ; I think no problem will occurred.

Comment: Tried all the rest only this worked for me, thanks

Comment: It's funny that we need so much code for such a simple thing.

Comment: It's not working for google photos app. I changed `content` to `contentprovider` in the String in `isGooglePhotosUri` function. `isGooglePhotosUri` is returning true for Android 13. However the returning String is a number like 2003661742.  What should be the next step for solution?

Comment: The shown code does not compile! The static method `getPath()` refers to the instance variable `context`. Making it non-static didn't help - it then ends in an exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4324)`. 
Thus: not working!

Answer (score 54):

**Get path from URI Use below class for android all version.
access any type of File**.

```
package com.satya.filemangerdemo.common;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class FileUtils {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
                if (fullPath != "") {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    final String id;
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                        }
                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                        };
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            try {
                                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));

                         /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/

                                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                            }
                        }


                    }

                } else {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final boolean isOreo = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O;
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                }


            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;

                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                  selection = "_id=?";
                 selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            } else if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
        }


        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }

            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
             if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
             {
                // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                 return getMediaFilePathForN(uri, context);
                // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
             }else
             {

                 return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
             }


        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check if a file exists on device
     *
     * @param filePath The absolute file path
     */
    private static boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        return file.exists();
    }


    /**
     * Get full file path from external storage
     *
     * @param pathData The storage type and the relative path
     */
    private static String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
        final String type = pathData[0];
        final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
        String fullPath = "";

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath;
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    private static String getMediaFilePathForN(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }


    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                        String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Drive.
     */
    private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


}
```

But now according to the android latest guideline, you could not direct access getExternalStorageDirectory(). You need to implement a workaround for this

Comment: we can access path using String strPath = FileUtils.getPath(uri));

Comment: updated version of above code can be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/60642994#answer-60642994

Comment: Do we have an updated answer for the same without using deprecated getExternalStorageDirectory(), @Nadeem Iqbal? –

Comment: @MdBasha : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/60642994#answer-60642994

Comment: not working on android 11

Answer (score 25):

Try this.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
{
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
     int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Code edits often get rejected. [I noticed one suggesting an alternative function that is not deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3563204)

Comment: this is giving me null cursor, uri is something like this - file:///

Comment: @MartinSmith Still getting `null`

Comment: @AnkitaShah : You have to try below answer for different android version

Answer (score 21):

**You can use get File path from diffrent SDk versions**

Use RealPathUtils for it

```
public class RealPathUtils {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index
            = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
}
```

**Now get the file Path from URI **

```
 String path = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                    path = RealPathUtils.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(MainActivity.this, uri);

                    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
                else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                    path = RealPathUtils.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(MainActivity.this, uri);

                    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
                else
                    path = RealPathUtils.getRealPathFromURI_API19(MainActivity.this, uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
                // Get the file instance
                 File file = new File(path);
```

Comment: This is only for MediaStore.Images.Media  . If you want to get another files than you can use with MediaStore.FileColumns

I am showing the process !

Answer (score 14):

```
package com.utils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileUtils {

    /* Get uri related content real local file path. */
    public static String getPath(Context ctx, Uri uri) {
        String ret;
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                // Android OS above sdk version 19.
                ret = getUriRealPathAboveKitkat(ctx, uri);
            } else {
                // Android OS below sdk version 19
                ret = getRealPath(ctx.getContentResolver(), uri, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("DREG", "FilePath Catch: " + e);
            ret = getFilePathFromURI(ctx, uri);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static String getFilePathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        //copy file and send new file path
        String fileName = getFileName(contentUri);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            String TEMP_DIR_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File copyFile = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH + File.separator + fileName);
            Log.d("DREG", "FilePath copyFile: " + copyFile);
            copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
            return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) return null;
        String fileName = null;
        String path = uri.getPath();
        int cut = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            fileName = path.substring(cut + 1);
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    public static void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
            if (inputStream == null) return;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
            IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream); // org.apache.commons.io
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { // IOException
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private static String getUriRealPathAboveKitkat(Context ctx, Uri uri) {
        String ret = "";

        if (ctx != null && uri != null) {

            if (isContentUri(uri)) {
                if (isGooglePhotoDoc(uri.getAuthority())) {
                    ret = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                } else {
                    ret = getRealPath(ctx.getContentResolver(), uri, null);
                }
            } else if (isFileUri(uri)) {
                ret = uri.getPath();
            } else if (isDocumentUri(ctx, uri)) {

                // Get uri related document id.
                String documentId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                // Get uri authority.
                String uriAuthority = uri.getAuthority();

                if (isMediaDoc(uriAuthority)) {
                    String idArr[] = documentId.split(":");
                    if (idArr.length == 2) {
                        // First item is document type.
                        String docType = idArr[0];

                        // Second item is document real id.
                        String realDocId = idArr[1];

                        // Get content uri by document type.
                        Uri mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        if ("image".equals(docType)) {
                            mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("video".equals(docType)) {
                            mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("audio".equals(docType)) {
                            mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        }

                        // Get where clause with real document id.
                        String whereClause = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = " + realDocId;

                        ret = getRealPath(ctx.getContentResolver(), mediaContentUri, whereClause);
                    }

                } else if (isDownloadDoc(uriAuthority)) {
                    // Build download uri.
                    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads");

                    // Append download document id at uri end.
                    Uri downloadUriAppendId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(downloadUri, Long.valueOf(documentId));

                    ret = getRealPath(ctx.getContentResolver(), downloadUriAppendId, null);

                } else if (isExternalStoreDoc(uriAuthority)) {
                    String idArr[] = documentId.split(":");
                    if (idArr.length == 2) {
                        String type = idArr[0];
                        String realDocId = idArr[1];

                        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            ret = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + realDocId;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this uri represent a document or not. */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private static boolean isDocumentUri(Context ctx, Uri uri) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if (ctx != null && uri != null) {
            ret = DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(ctx, uri);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this uri is a content uri or not.
     *  content uri like content://media/external/images/media/1302716
     *  */
    private static boolean isContentUri(Uri uri) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if (uri != null) {
            String uriSchema = uri.getScheme();
            if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uriSchema)) {
                ret = true;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this uri is a file uri or not.
     *  file uri like file:///storage/41B7-12F1/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180211_095139.jpg
     * */
    private static boolean isFileUri(Uri uri) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if (uri != null) {
            String uriSchema = uri.getScheme();
            if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uriSchema)) {
                ret = true;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this document is provided by ExternalStorageProvider. */
    private static boolean isExternalStoreDoc(String uriAuthority) {
        boolean ret = false;

        if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uriAuthority)) {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this document is provided by DownloadsProvider. */
    private static boolean isDownloadDoc(String uriAuthority) {
        boolean ret = false;

        if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uriAuthority)) {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this document is provided by MediaProvider. */
    private static boolean isMediaDoc(String uriAuthority) {
        boolean ret = false;

        if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uriAuthority)) {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Check whether this document is provided by google photos. */
    private static boolean isGooglePhotoDoc(String uriAuthority) {
        boolean ret = false;

        if ("com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uriAuthority)) {
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /* Return uri represented document file real local path.*/
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private static String getRealPath(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri, String whereClause) {
        String ret = "";

        // Query the uri with condition.
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, whereClause, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            boolean moveToFirst = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (moveToFirst) {

                // Get columns name by uri type.
                String columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

                if (uri == MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                } else if (uri == MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
                } else if (uri == MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
                }

                // Get column index.
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);

                // Get column value which is the uri related file local path.
                ret = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

}
```

**in build.gradle file 
add this**

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

Now call `FileUtils.getPath(context, uri);` from your main class.

Comment: This solution works for picking a file for all shared storage folders. I'm uploading to Firebase Storage and I tried all the other solutions but when you pick a files from other locations they were causing FileNotFoundException. This works perfectly

Comment: Worked for me among all other solutions for json file almost in every location.

Answer (score 6):

I know this has already been answered.but there are some issues I found in the comments. I found a great reliable solution forked from [here](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java)

**to use it**  `File file=FileUtils.getFile(uri);`

```
public class FileUtils {

//replace this with your authority
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents";


private FileUtils() {
} //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

/**
 * TAG for log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging


/**
 * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
 */
public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
    if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if (DEBUG)
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
 * <br>
 * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
 * represents a local file.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri     The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 * @see #isLocal(String)
 * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {


    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // LocalStorageProvider
        if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            // The path is the id
            return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        }
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Convert Uri into File, if possible.
 *
 * @return file A local file that the Uri was pointing to, or null if the
 * Uri is unsupported or pointed to a remote resource.
 * @author paulburke
 * @see #getPath(Context, Uri)
 */
public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null) {
        String path = getPath(context, uri);
        if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
            return new File(path);
        }
    }
    return null;
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but on external memory not getting the perfect path for Android L

Comment: I did not add the full class. check the link and use the full class. I am sure it will fix your problem.

Comment: Yap, I try it also but the same result :(

Comment: This seems to fails when file is on external SD card (returns nulls).. Any solution?

Comment: @Snake did you find any solution for that?

Comment: It works for almost all of the paths I tested expect for downloads folder, any solution?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this function for get file from uri in new android and older

```
fun getFileFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri?): File? {
    uri ?: return null
    uri.path ?: return null

    var newUriString = uri.toString()
    newUriString = newUriString.replace(
        "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/",
        "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/"
    )
    newUriString = newUriString.replace(
        "/msf%3A", "/image%3A"
    )
    val newUri = Uri.parse(newUriString)

    var realPath = String()
    val databaseUri: Uri
    val selection: String?
    val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    if (newUri.path?.contains("/document/image:") == true) {
        databaseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        selection = "_id=?"
        selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(newUri).split(":")[1])
    } else {
        databaseUri = newUri
        selection = null
        selectionArgs = null
    }
    try {
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            databaseUri,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )
        cursor?.let {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("GetFileUri Exception:", e.message ?: "")
    }
    val path = realPath.ifEmpty {
        when {
            newUri.path?.contains("/document/raw:") == true -> newUri.path?.replace(
                "/document/raw:",
                ""
            )
            newUri.path?.contains("/document/primary:") == true -> newUri.path?.replace(
                "/document/primary:",
                "/storage/emulated/0/"
            )
            else -> return null
        }
    }
    return if (path.isNullOrEmpty()) null else File(path)
}
```

Comment: It's not accessing file in download folder

Comment: can you show me your code?
I use this code and It works for me for all folder and all androids

Comment: below ans (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469368/9764941) works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Snippet code when you receive file path.

```
 Uri fileUri = data.getData();
 FilePathHelper filePathHelper = new FilePathHelper();
 String path = "";
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
       if (filePathHelper.getPathnew(fileUri, this) != null) {
              path = filePathHelper.getPathnew(fileUri, this).toLowerCase();
       } else {
              path = filePathHelper.getFilePathFromURI(fileUri, this).toLowerCase();
       }
 } else {
       path = filePathHelper.getPath(fileUri, this).toLowerCase();
 }
```

Bellow is a class which can be accessed by creating new object. you will also need to add to a dependency in gradel `implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'`

```
public class FilePathHelper {

    public FilePathHelper(){

    }

    public String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url.replace(" ", ""));
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public String getFilePathFromURI(Uri contentUri, Context context) {
        //copy file and send new file path
        String fileName = getFileName(contentUri);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            File copyFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
            copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
            return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
            if (inputStream == null) return;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        String filePath = null;
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        if (isKitKat) {
            filePath = generateFromKitkat(uri, context);
        }

        if (filePath != null) {
            return filePath;
        }

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath == null ? uri.getPath() : filePath;
    }

    @TargetApi(19)
    private String generateFromKitkat(Uri uri, Context context) {
        String filePath = null;
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

            String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

            String[] column = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
            String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
                    query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);


            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) return null;
        String fileName = null;
        String path = uri.getPath();
        int cut = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            fileName = path.substring(cut + 1);
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public String getPathnew(Uri uri, Context context) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something with exception - " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the check for SDK inside the filePathHelper

Answer (score 2):

```
  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

Using this method we can get string filepath from Uri.

Comment: I hope so, not confirm because this is what i was doing in 2020 & worked perfectly fine.

Comment: it works only if you choose an image from recent images and always crashes if you are trying to get path from any folder

Comment: I moved to flutter so I may not help you further but let me know if you really need this.

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin:

Just create a new file with name **URIPathHelper.kt**. Then copy and paste the following Utility class in your file. It covers all scenarios and works perfectly for all Android versions. Its explanation will be discussed later.

```
package com.mvp.handyopinion

import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.provider.MediaStore

class URIPathHelper {

    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKatorAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatorAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                }

            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }
}
```

**How to Use URIPathHelper class to get path from URI**

```
val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
val filePath = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, YOUR_URI_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: [] im getting this error while trying to add aduio file

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated

Comment: it's not working in Android 12 and higher OS version

Answer (score 2):

Since most of the solutions here don't work on API 30+ where  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated, or parse the document id which is system-internal information, it is worth asking: do you really *need* the path?

If you simply need a way to access the item's data, there is a  straightforward way to do that on all platforms:

```
fun getInputStream(context: Context, uri: Uri): InputStream? {
    return context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
}
```

If you need the display name (such as *test.jpg*), you can also use the content resolver:

```
fun getDisplayName(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
        .use {
            if (it == null || !it.moveToFirst()) {
                return null
            }

            val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            if (columnIndex == -1) {
                return null
            }

            return it.getString(columnIndex)
        }
}
```

Just thought I'd mention it because it would have helped me.

For Java:

```
InputStream getInputStream(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    return context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
}
```

and for those who need to know length of the stream:

```
InputStream is = getInputStream(context, uri);
int length = is.available();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get any sort of file path use this (taken from https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

```
package com.yourpackage;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Peli
 * @author paulburke (ipaulpro)
 * @version 2013-12-11
 */
public class FileUtils {
    private FileUtils() {
    } //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

    /**
     * TAG for log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true; // Set to true to enable logging

    public static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

    public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";

    /**
     * Gets the extension of a file name, like ".png" or ".jpg".
     *
     * @param uri
     * @return Extension including the dot("."); "" if there is no extension;
     * null if uri was null.
     */
    public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
     */
    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if Uri is a MediaStore Uri.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaUri(Uri uri) {
        return "media".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Convert File into Uri.
     *
     * @param file
     * @return uri
     */
    public static Uri getUri(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path only (without file name).
     *
     * @param file
     * @return
     */
    public static File getPathWithoutFilename(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // no file to be split off. Return everything
                return file;
            } else {
                String filename = file.getName();
                String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                // Construct path without file name.
                String pathwithoutname = filepath.substring(0,
                        filepath.length() - filename.length());
                if (pathwithoutname.endsWith("/")) {
                    pathwithoutname = pathwithoutname.substring(0, pathwithoutname.length() - 1);
                }
                return new File(pathwithoutname);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the given file.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(File file) {

        String extension = getExtension(file.getName());

        if (extension.length() > 0)
            return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1));

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the give Uri.
     */
    public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
        File file = new File(getPath(context, uri));
        return getMimeType(file);
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is {@link LocalStorageProvider}.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return LocalStorageProvider.AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will quickGet the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #isLocal(String)
     * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );
        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

//                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
//                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
//                }
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                try {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "getPath: id= " + id);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
                    if(segments.size() > 1) {
                        String rawPath = segments.get(1);
                        if(!rawPath.startsWith("/")){
                            return rawPath.substring(rawPath.indexOf("/"));
                        }else {
                            return rawPath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Uri into File, if possible.
     *
     * @return file A local file that the Uri was pointing to, or null if the
     * Uri is unsupported or pointed to a remote resource.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #getPath(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the file size in a human-readable string.
     *
     * @param size
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getReadableFileSize(int size) {
        final int BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES = 1024;
        final DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        final String KILOBYTES = " KB";
        final String MEGABYTES = " MB";
        final String GIGABYTES = " GB";
        float fileSize = 0;
        String suffix = KILOBYTES;

        if (size > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
            fileSize = size / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
            if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                if (fileSize > BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES) {
                    fileSize = fileSize / BYTES_IN_KILOBYTES;
                    suffix = GIGABYTES;
                } else {
                    suffix = MEGABYTES;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(dec.format(fileSize) + suffix);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given File from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param file
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, File file) {
        return getThumbnail(context, getUri(file), getMimeType(file));
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given Uri from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) {
        return getThumbnail(context, uri, getMimeType(context, uri));
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to retrieve the thumbnail of given Uri from the MediaStore. This
     * should not be called on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @param mimeType
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri, String mimeType) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to quickGet thumbnail");

        if (!isMediaUri(uri)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "You can only retrieve thumbnails for images and videos.");
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (uri != null) {
            final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got thumb ID: " + id);

                    if (mimeType.contains("video")) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    } else if (mimeType.contains(FileUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE)) {
                        bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                resolver,
                                id,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                                null);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.e(TAG, "getThumbnail", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return bm;
    }

    /**
     * File and folder comparator. TODO Expose sorting option method
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Comparator<File> sComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            // Sort alphabetically by lower case, which is much cleaner
            return f1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(
                    f2.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    };

    /**
     * File (not directories) filter.
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static FileFilter sFileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return files only (not directories) and skip hidden files
            return file.isFile() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Folder (directories) filter.
     *
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static FileFilter sDirFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            final String fileName = file.getName();
            // Return directories only and skip hidden directories
            return file.isDirectory() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Get the Intent for selecting content to be used in an Intent Chooser.
     *
     * @return The intent for opening a file with Intent.createChooser()
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // The MIME data type filter
        intent.setType("*/*");
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @K40S, nowadays this code is available from many sources. I have taken from another source though, but couldn't able to remember it. 
However, I have added your source in my solution. Stolen is a harsh word in that respect.

Comment: Taken without credit, while violating the license terms (attach license to code) is stealing.

I didn't want to shame you or something, just wanted to use the correct word :)

Comment: If you see the pasted code you will see that all the comments which are related with the real author are not removed from that answer. I kept it intentionally and sorry for not giving the exact link.

Comment: Use this file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u5QC5omPLnteWy_luBPZ8l5aXMPB--nA
In that class use your package name and R.java file.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is getting the path of the download directory or msf and NumberFormat exception, Try this one. It worked for me correctly

```
    package com.example.bookingmelbourne;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    
    public class FileUtils {
        private static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    @WorkerThread
    @Nullable
    public static String getReadablePathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {

        String path = null;
        if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = uri.getPath();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            path = getPath(context, uri);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            return path;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "get path from uri: " + path);
        if (!isReadablePath(path)) {
            int index = path.lastIndexOf("/");
            String name = path.substring(index + 1);
            String dstPath = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name;
            if (copyFile(context, uri, dstPath)) {
                path = dstPath;
                Log.d(TAG, "copy file success: " + path);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "copy file fail!");
            } 
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                Log.d("External Storage", docId);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                String dstPath = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getFileName(context,uri);

                 if (copyFile(context, uri, dstPath)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "copy file success: " + dstPath);
                    return dstPath;

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "copy file fail!");
                }


            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getFileName(Context context, Uri uri) {

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        int nameindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return  cursor.getString(nameindex);
    }


    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                        String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isReadablePath(@Nullable String path) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean isLocalPath;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                File localFile = new File(path);
                isLocalPath = localFile.exists() && localFile.canRead();
            } else {
                isLocalPath = false;
            }
        } else {
            isLocalPath = path.startsWith(File.separator);
        }
        return isLocalPath;
    }

    private static boolean copyFile(Context context, Uri uri, String dstPath) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstPath);

            byte[] buff = new byte[100 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

  }
```

After that, you can call this method passing context and uri objects

```
FileUtils.getReadablePathFromUri(context,uri)
```

Comment: It dont show correct path

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting android 11 (api level 30) or above, even if you get the file path from the uri you will not able to access the file and you will find FileNotFoundException (permission denied)

Because from android 11 apps are only allowed to access file from own app-specific directories(ex: Android/data/packagename).

However there is a permission called

> MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

which allow apps to access all files of storage. But if you want to publish your app to play store, according to store policy this permission is not allowed for all types of apps. check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files)

So what's the solution?

You can get inputstream from URI and use that if it is suitable for your use cases(ex uploading file through retrofit, convert to bitmap etc)

if you desperately need File object then you have to convert the inputstream to file and store it in your app-specific directory.

```
object FileUtils {

val cRes = BaseApplication.instance.contentResolver



@Throws(IOException::class)
fun getInputStream(uri:Uri): InputStream? {
    return if (isVirtualFile(uri)){
        getInputStreamForVirtualFile(uri, getMimeType(uri))
    }else{
        cRes.openInputStream(uri)
    }
}

fun getMimeType(uri: Uri): String? {
    return cRes.getType(uri)
}

private fun isVirtualFile(uri: Uri): Boolean {

    if (!DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(BaseApplication.instance, uri)) {
        return false
    }

    val cursor: Cursor? = cRes.query(
        uri,
        arrayOf(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_FLAGS),
        null,
        null,
        null
    )

    val flags: Int = cursor?.use {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.getInt(0)
        } else {
            0
        }
    } ?: 0

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        flags and DocumentsContract.Document.FLAG_VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT != 0
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getInputStreamForVirtualFile(
    uri: Uri, mimeTypeFilter: String?): FileInputStream? {

    if (mimeTypeFilter==null){
        throw FileNotFoundException()
    }
    val openableMimeTypes: Array<String>? =
        cRes.getStreamTypes(uri, mimeTypeFilter)

    return if (openableMimeTypes?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        cRes
            .openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(uri, openableMimeTypes[0], null)?.createInputStream()
    } else {
        throw FileNotFoundException()
    }
}

fun copyStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputFile: File) {
    inputStream.use { input ->
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        outputStream.use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
            while (true) {
                val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                if (byteCount < 0) break
                output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
            }
            output.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

}

While opening file picker use this

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
```

Not

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

## its support android 11.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class GetFile {
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        File destinationFilename = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separatorChar + queryName(context, uri));

        try (InputStream ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
            createFileFromStream(ins, destinationFilename);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Save File", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return destinationFilename;
    }

    public static void createFileFromStream(InputStream ins, File destination) {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = ins.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Save File", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String queryName(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    result = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
// For document file
val documentFile = DocumentFileCompat.fromUri(context, uri)
val path = documentFile.absolutePath // e.g. /storage/emulated/0/Music/Torisetsu.mp3

// For media file
val mediaFile = MediaFile(context, uri)
val path = mediaFile.absolutePath // e.g. /storage/emulated/0/Music/My Love.mp3
```

To check whether the URI is media file or document file, use `isMediaDocument` extension function:

```kotlin
val isMediaFile = uri.isMediaDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

This saved my day. The simplest approach to get the path from URI.

```
  //kotlin
  myuri = data.data
  val realPath = myuri.path
  Log.d(TAG, "path: $realPath")
```

Returns path :

```
 path: /storage/emulated/0/Download/CutOFF - Escuro (Original Mix).mp3
```

Comment: some device is returning "content://..." as your `realPath` and it is simply not working

Answer (score 0):

**Working for all api version (tested on Android 10)**

```
val returnCursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
            val columnIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
            val path = returnCursor.getString(columnIndex)
```

Comment: Is it for images only?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to file and want to avoid using `ContentResolver` or directly reading file, see answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67499473/6367262

Answer (score 0):

If this file(video or image) did not update in MediaStore space(You need to reboot device to update MS sometimes)

Try this:

```
 Uri uri;         
 int index=uri.getPath().indexOf("/storage");
 String path=uri.getPath().substring(index);
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer of @S.A.Parkhid on kotlin.

```
class FileUtils @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {

    private var selection: String? = null
    private var selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null

    fun getFile(uri: Uri): File? {
        val path = getPath(uri)
        return if (path != null) {
            File(path)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun getPath(uri: Uri): String? {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getPathForKitKatAndAbove(uri)
        } else {
            getPathBelowKitKat(uri)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun handleExternalStorage(uri: Uri): String? {
        val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
        val fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split)
        return if (fullPath !== "") {
            fullPath
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun handleDownloads(uri: Uri): String? {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            handleDownloads23ApiAndAbove(uri)
        } else {
            handleDownloadsBelow23Api(uri)
        }
        return null
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun handleDownloadsBelow23Api(uri: Uri): String? {
        val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
            return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
        }
        var contentUri: Uri? = null
        try {
            contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), id.toLong()
            )
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            log(e)
        }
        if (contentUri != null) {
            return getDataColumn(contentUri)
        }
        return null
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun handleDownloads23ApiAndAbove(uri: Uri): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver
                .query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val fileName = cursor.getString(0)
                val path: String =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                if (path.isNotEmpty()) {
                    return path
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        val id: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        if (id.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
            }
            val contentUriPrefixesToTry = arrayOf(
                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
            )
            for (contentUriPrefix in contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                return try {
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix),
                        id.toLong()
                    )
                    getDataColumn(contentUri)
                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                    //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                    uri.path.orEmpty().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:".toRegex(), "")
                        .replaceFirst("^raw:".toRegex(), "")
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun handleMedia(uri: Uri): String? {
        val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
        val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
        val contentUri: Uri? = when (split[0]) {
            "image" -> {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            "video" -> {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            "audio" -> {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            else -> null
        }
        selection = "_id=?"
        selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
        return if (contentUri != null) {
            getDataColumn(contentUri)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun handleContentScheme(uri: Uri): String? {
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
            return uri.lastPathSegment
        }
        if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
            return getDriveFilePath(uri)
        }
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            copyFileToInternalStorage(uri, "userfiles")
        } else {
            getDataColumn(uri)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun getPathForKitKatAndAbove(uri: Uri): String? {
        return when {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            isExternalStorageDocument(uri) -> handleExternalStorage(uri)
            // DownloadsProvider
            isDownloadsDocument(uri) -> handleDownloads(uri)
            // MediaProvider
            isMediaDocument(uri) -> handleMedia(uri)
            //GoogleDriveProvider
            isGoogleDriveUri(uri) -> getDriveFilePath(uri)
            //WhatsAppProvider
            isWhatsAppFile(uri) -> getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri)
            //ContentScheme
            "content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> handleContentScheme(uri)
            //FileScheme
            "file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> uri.path
            else -> null
        }
    }

    private fun getPathBelowKitKat(uri: Uri): String? {
        if (isWhatsAppFile(uri)) {
            return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri)
        }
        if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            )
            var cursor: Cursor? = null
            try {
                cursor = context.contentResolver
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                log(e)
            } finally {
                cursor?.close()
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun fileExists(filePath: String): Boolean {
        val file = File(filePath)
        return file.exists()
    }

    private fun getPathFromExtSD(pathData: Array<String>): String {
        val type = pathData[0]
        val relativePath = "/" + pathData[1]
        var fullPath: String

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + relativePath
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE").orEmpty() + relativePath
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath
        }
        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE").orEmpty() + relativePath
        return if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            fullPath
        } else fullPath
    }

    private fun getDriveFilePath(uri: Uri): String? {
        context.contentResolver.query(
            uri, null, null, null, null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            /*
             * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
             *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
             *     * and display it.
             * */
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            val file = File(context.cacheDir, name)
            try {
                val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                val bytesAvailable = inputStream.available()

                val bufferSize = min(bytesAvailable, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
                val buffers = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                var read: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buffers).also { read = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
                }
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                log(e)
            } finally {
                cursor.close()
            }
            return file.path
        }
        return null
    }

    /***
     * Used for Android Q+
     * @param uri
     * @param newDirName if you want to create a directory, you can set this variable
     * @return
     */
    private fun copyFileToInternalStorage(uri: Uri, newDirName: String): String? {
        context.contentResolver.query(
            uri, arrayOf(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE), null, null, null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            /*
             * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
             *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
             *     * and display it.
             * */
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            val output: File = if (newDirName != "") {
                val dir = File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName)
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir()
                }
                File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name)
            } else {
                File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + name)
            }
            try {
                val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return null
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(output)
                var read: Int
                val buffers = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                while (inputStream.read(buffers).also { read = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
                }
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                log(e)
            } finally {
                cursor.close()
            }
            return output.path
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri: Uri): String? {
        return copyFileToInternalStorage(uri, "whatsapp")
    }

    private fun getDataColumn(uri: Uri): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null
            )
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CONTENT == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_CONTENT == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return MEDIA_DOCUMENT_CONTENT == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return GOOGLE_PHOTOS_CONTENT == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isWhatsAppFile(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return WHATS_APP_CONTENT == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isGoogleDriveUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return GOOGLE_DRIVE_CONTENT == uri.authority || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy" == uri.authority
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        private const val MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024
        private const val GOOGLE_DRIVE_CONTENT = "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage"
        private const val WHATS_APP_CONTENT = "com.whatsapp.provider.media"
        private const val GOOGLE_PHOTOS_CONTENT = "com.google.android.apps.photos.content"
        private const val MEDIA_DOCUMENT_CONTENT = "com.android.providers.media.documents"
        private const val DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_CONTENT = "com.android.providers.downloads.documents"
        private const val EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CONTENT = "com.android.externalstorage.documents"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Nullable
private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final String column = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * get path from Uri (Method 1)
 *
 * @param uri set Uri
 * @return you will get path here
 */
@Nullable
public String getPathOf(@Nullable Uri uri) {
    String path = null;
    if (uri != null) {
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(mContext, uri)) {
            if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                }

                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris
                        .withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.parseLong(id));

                path = getDataColumn(mContext, contentUri, null, null);
            } else if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final Uri contentUri = getUri(split);

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                path = getDataColumn(mContext, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = getDataColumn(mContext, uri, null, null);
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = uri.getPath();
        }

        if (path != null) {
            try {
                return URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Nullable
private static Uri getUri(@NonNull String[] split) {
    final String type = split[0];
    Uri contentUri = null;
    if ("image" .equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("video" .equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("audio" .equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    return contentUri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I had a hard time trying to figure this out on Xamarin. From the suggestions above I came up with this solution.

```
private string getRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri contentUri)
{
    string filename = "";
    string thepath = "";
    Android.Net.Uri filePathUri;
    ICursor cursor = this.ContentResolver.Query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
    {
        int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);//Instead of "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA" can be used "_data"
        filePathUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(cursor.GetString(column_index));
        filename = filePathUri.LastPathSegment;
        thepath = filePathUri.Path;
    }

    return thepath;
}
```

Comment: `Android 7.0` Column_Index is `-1` when picking a file using `ActionContentGet` and type `*/*` for lets say a PDF

Answer (score -2):

We all agree that SAF is horribly designed and *slow*, but Google has been pushing us to it. Given that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` had been long deprecated, and possibly won't work since 11, I would rather not using these solutions, as it is one update away from crashing...

Comment: so what is your suggested answer anyway? you are supposed to provide a solid answer and solution am I not? you are expressing your opinion here "as an answer"

Comment: @elliotching Agree, downvote me then. I was frustrated (as people were still working to update the code), got emotional (I had the same problem, and couldn't accept a hacky solution), and typed this. In my defense, the answers are hacky, non-reliable, non-testable. Why didn't I edit the answer: too many, and SO requires answer to be not drastically changed. Why didn't I comment: too many.

Answer (score -30):

```
String uri_path = "file:///mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3";
File f = new removeUriFromPath(uri_path));
public static String removeUriFromPath(String uri)
{
  return  uri.substring(7, uri.length());
}
```

Comment: my bro using a substring is not a solution, cause uri_path is dynamic !