# Get Real Path For Uri Android

Tags: android, string, path, uri, android-videoview

I am developing a `VideoPlayer`. I convert the `URI` of a launched intent to a string and it gives me `content://media/external.....`. But I need to get the real path.

**For example:** `/storage/extSdcard....`.

How do I do this?

**Here is my code if needed:**

```
videoURI = getIntent().getData();
vv.setVideoURI(videoURI);

videoName = videoURI.toString();

tvTitle.setText(videoName);
```

Answer (score 53):

Use this code .This is working for all android version.This is tested code.This support all devices

```
public static String getPathFromUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: how is this working on all Android version when `DocumentsContract` itself is only available since API level 19 KitKat? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html

Comment: Use this code then you will come to know it is working in all the devices and there are condition according to api levels.

Comment: should have mentioned the original answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27271131/1567541

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA getPathFromUri() will return null for external sdcard files.Any solution for that??

Comment: What will happen if the storage is a memory card? non-primary get's null if use this method in Android L

Comment: its not working on android 7. stops with this error:  column '_data' does not exist

Comment: Can you please tell me the device name which i can test it in

Comment: column '_data' does not exists in android 7 and above

Comment: Is working with real path a recommended practice?

Comment: it crashes when from non primary download folder : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9999, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:11063 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.alquran.tafhimul_quran/com.alquran.tafhimul_quran.OnlineSavingFiles}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:11063"

Answer (score 18):

In Kotlin by using this function we can get the real path from URI:

here is the code of `getRealPathFromURI`

```
fun getRealPathFromURI(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    when {
        // DocumentProvider
        DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri) -> {
            when {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                isExternalStorageDocument(uri) -> {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]
                    // This is for checking Main Memory
                    return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        if (split.size > 1) {
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                        } else {
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                        }
                        // This is for checking SD Card
                    } else {
                        "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/")
                    }
                }
                isDownloadsDocument(uri) -> {
                    val fileName = getFilePath(context, uri)
                    if (fileName != null) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                    }
                    var id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        id = id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                        val file = File(id)
                        if (file.exists()) return id
                    }
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                }
                isMediaDocument(uri) -> {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]
                    var contentUri: Uri? = null
                    when (type) {
                        "image" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        "video" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        "audio" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                    }
                    val selection = "_id=?"
                    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
                }
            }
        }
        "content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> {
            // Return the remote address
            return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        }
        "file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true) -> {
            return uri.path
        }
    }
    return null
}

fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
                  selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(
            column
    )
    try {
        if (uri == null) return null
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}


fun getFilePath(context: Context, uri: Uri?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
    )
    try {
        if (uri == null) return null
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
}
```

Get the real path bypassing URI to `getRealPathFromURI` function in your activity or fragment:

```
val fileRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(context!!, fileURI) ?: ""
```

Comment: Hello,
In my case, it goes into *isDownloadDocument* path, but _id is msf:24, not raw: & not a number.
Could you help?

Comment: @SanskarDahiya Try this way if `id.startsWith("msf:")` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154537/2462531

Comment: Hello,
I already checked this, But having issue for memory.
Thus, create some solution from Andorid Documentation:

 if (isAndroid10 && id.startsWith("msf:")) {
                            final String[] split = id.split(":");

                            final String selection = "_id=?";
                            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };
                            return getDataColumn(context, MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, selection, selectionArgs);
                        }

Comment: Please post it as a new question then

Comment: @ShailendraMadda here the variable fileRealPath is null in my case. Would you please help me out

Comment: From where you are trying to access the file? @YashBhardwaj

Answer (score 15):

You can use this code for selected video path.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
   String yourRealPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
} else {
   //boooo, cursor doesn't have rows ...
}
cursor.close();
```

you can refer the below link for your help.

[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

**Latest with File provider (API 29):**

please follow links :

Blogs: https://blogs.datanapps.com/media-picker
Github : https://github.com/datanapps/MediaPicker

I hope you will success.

Comment: try this might be its helpful for you. other wise i will update my ans tomorrow. 
 https://www.journaldev.com/23219/android-capture-image-camera-gallery-using-fileprovider

Comment: @PriyankaSingh please try this link hope it will help full for you. 
   https://github.com/datanapps/MediaPicker

Answer (score 7):

Here's something I have used before:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI (Uri contentUri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
       path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: cursor  is  null .

Comment: This works for media content (from the media content providers), but not for Storage Access Framework files.

Comment: @PriyankaSingh you have already accepted an answer. If you have gotten a little further along and now have a slightly different problem please post a new, specific question

Comment: @KenWolf Accepted answer is not working for all version.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the answers doesnt work for both gallery and camera images. this works for me.

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    Log.i("URI",uri+"");
    String result = uri+"";
    // DocumentProvider 
    //  if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) { 
    if (isKitKat && (result.contains("media.documents"))) {
        String[] ary = result.split("/");
        int length = ary.length;
        String imgary = ary[length-1];
        final String[] dat = imgary.split("%3A");
        final String docId = dat[1];
        final String type = dat[0];
        Uri contentUri = null;
        if ("image".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
        } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
        } 
        final String selection = "_id=?";
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            dat[1]
        }; 
        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
    } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    } 
    // File 
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    } 
    return null; 
} 

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
        column
    }; 
    try { 
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null); 
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } 
    } finally { 
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();
            System.out.println("picturePath +"+ picturePath );  //path of sdcard

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to get real path of the file from Uri via MediaStore::

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
        return "";
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work on Android 10 or higher, as `DATA` is no longer accessible. It is unreliable on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: does this work for other files types such as audio?
also as @CommonsWare said ```DATA```  is deprecated

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

here i get uri from on onActivityResult()

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI);
```

1) In fragment you can use function like this way..

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String filePath;
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { 
            filePath = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            filePath = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

2) And activity you can use function like that.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String filePath;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { 
            filePath = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            filePath = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it like

```
 Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData(); //where data is intent return by onActivityResult

imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
```

and code for gettingPath..

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) 
{
    String result = null;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) 
    { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    }
    else 
    { 
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin folks, This code works for me

```
fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val isKitKatorAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKatorAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
            }

        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            var contentUri: Uri? = null
            if ("image" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("video" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("audio" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            val selection = "_id=?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
        }
    } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return uri.path
    }
    return null
}

fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(column)
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val column_index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            return cursor.getString(column_index)
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
    }
    return null
}

fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
}

fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
}

fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
}
```

You can add these methods in your utils class

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this problem for 2/3 days, none of the possible solutions I found were helpful. I kept getting null cursors and similar errors.

My reason for needing the file path was to get Exif data so I could display images in the correct orientation. (See [A final answer on how to get Exif data from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696787/a-final-answer-on-how-to-get-exif-data-from-uri))

I found this open source project -

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/BitmapUtils.java

There is a method that gets Exif data from an InputStream, this fixed my problem -

```
ExifInterface ei = null;
try 
{
    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (is != null) 
    {
        ei = new ExifInterface(is);
        is.close();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ignored) 
{
}
```

I know this isn't answering the question directly, but since I found this thread by trying to solve this problem, I think my answer may help others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function for get file from uri in new android and older

```
fun getFileFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri?): File? {
    uri ?: return null
    uri.path ?: return null

    var newUriString = uri.toString()
    newUriString = newUriString.replace(
        "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/",
        "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/"
    )
    newUriString = newUriString.replace(
        "/msf%3A", "/image%3A"
    )
    val newUri = Uri.parse(newUriString)

    var realPath = String()
    val databaseUri: Uri
    val selection: String?
    val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    if (newUri.path?.contains("/document/image:") == true) {
        databaseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        selection = "_id=?"
        selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(newUri).split(":")[1])
    } else {
        databaseUri = newUri
        selection = null
        selectionArgs = null
    }
    try {
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            databaseUri,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )
        cursor?.let {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("GetFileUri Exception:", e.message ?: "")
    }
    val path = realPath.ifEmpty {
        when {
            newUri.path?.contains("/document/raw:") == true -> newUri.path?.replace(
                "/document/raw:",
                ""
            )
            newUri.path?.contains("/document/primary:") == true -> newUri.path?.replace(
                "/document/primary:",
                "/storage/emulated/0/"
            )
            else -> return null
        }
    }
    return if (path.isNullOrEmpty()) null else File(path)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);
 String absolutePath = documentFile.getUri().getPath();
```

this will get the absolutePath from uri which is not in MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution that might be sufficient for some cases. In particular it's more a hack and handles primary storage and SD card storage only (for LG this also works with USB attached memory). It might be advisable to check the path afterwards, if it exists and is accessible. And note, that not every URI has a corresponding path, as some locations are only accessible via Google's proprietary SAF (speed factor about 1/200).

```
static String pathFromTreeUri(Uri uri)
{
    String uriPath = uri.getPath();
    if (uriPath != null)
    {
        if (uriPath.startsWith("/tree/primary:"))
        {
            return "/storage/emulated/0/" + uriPath.substring(14);
        }

        if ((uriPath.length() >= 17) &&
            (uriPath.substring(0, 16).matches("^/tree/....-....:$")))
        {
            return "/storage/" + uriPath.substring(6, 15) + "/" + uriPath.substring(16);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found more elegance solution:

```
Uri file_uri = Uri.parse(videoURI); // parse to Uri if your videoURI is string
String real_path = file_uri.getPath(); // will return real file path
```

Comment: It returns the MediaStore path

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.satya.filemangerdemo.common;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class FileUtils {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
                if (fullPath != "") {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    final String id;
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                        }
                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                        };
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            try {
                                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));

                         /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/

                                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                            }
                        }


                    }

                } else {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final boolean isOreo = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O;
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                }


            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;

                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            } else if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
        }


        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }

            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                return getMediaFilePathForN(uri, context);
                // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
            } else {

                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }


        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check if a file exists on device
     *
     * @param filePath The absolute file path
     */
    private static boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        return file.exists();
    }


    /**
     * Get full file path from external storage
     *
     * @param pathData The storage type and the relative path
     */
    private static String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
        final String type = pathData[0];
        final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
        String fullPath = "";

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath;
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    private static String getMediaFilePathForN(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }


    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                        String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri - The Uri to check.
     * @return - Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Drive.
     */
    private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


}
```

Comment: above code is working in android all devices as well as all type of file path open internal as well as external,google drive,gallary etc. note that remember to add fileprovider in android manifext.

Comment: It gives NPE in case of file from device's external storage with a `uriString` as `content://media/external/file...`. I've fixed it though in mine to get a pdf document.

Answer (score -1):

Real Path Utility class for Android, works for all API

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader;

public class RealPathUtil {

    public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
        else {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
        }
        return realPath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = 0;
        String result = "";
        if (cursor != null) {
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello,
In my case, it goes into *isDownloadDocument* path, but _id is msf:24, not raw: & not a number. Thus is throw error while using **Long.valueOf**
Could you help?

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting issue for same in Android 10,
as my file URI consist `msf:` format.
Most solutions said to copy files into cache path & then use that path.

Thus, here is solution to get path, without copying it.

```
 if (isAndroid10 && id.startsWith("msf:")) {
     final String[] split = id.split(":");
     final String selection = "_id=?";
     final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };
     return getDataColumn(context, MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, selection, selectionArgs);
}
```

Try to implement this.

```
MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI -- ONLY PRESENT FROM ANDROID 10
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Since I'm not an Android developer & This is working in my app. That's why I post this solution here.