# Real File Path Not Appearing

Tags: android, path, uri, android-videoview, video-player

I asked this  previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546176/1888770) and have edited it to suit my code for a Video Player running from an intent

```
videoURI = getIntent().getData();
vv.setVideoURI(videoURI);
```

but this gives me a blank string when I test it with `setText()`

How do I get this to work so I can get the full path for the launched video? EG. `/storage/extSdCard/Videos/Video.mp4`

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA` **instead of**  `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA`

Comment: String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
debug after this line using Log.d("mytest path etc",filePathColumn[0]); and see result ?