# Android - /document/ download path

Tags: android

So I'm making an app that requests a file from the phone's storage (external storage - not external SD Card, the internal one). But the path is awkward when I select the file from `Downloads: /document/`[number here, for example, 4].

Does anyone know how to get the real path of that file? Because it exists on the Download folder, but I wanted it to when it's selected, I get the real path of it and not that weird path which actually doesn't even exist. This happens at least on **Nougat** (Android Studio emulator) and on **KitKat** (both the emulator and my phone). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because in Nougat and above devices, It return document uri path instead of  file path.

Comment: you can check [here](http://technophilegeek.blogspot.com/2018/11/android-get-file-path-from-uri-real.html).

Comment: You are getting the URI. If you want to get the real path, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546561/7090731

Comment: Thank you both! It was really that. I didn't know. It was just shown as /document/number. The solution that worked was @AbhayKoradiya 's. Others I tried would return a NullPointerException but that one is very complete. Could you put that as a solution? Btw, that appears too in KitKat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Abhay Koradiya and Nandan Desai, the path was an Uri path, so I used this code to solve the problem and convert to normal path, given by Abhay Koradiya: http://technophilegeek.blogspot.com/2018/11/android-get-file-path-from-uri-real.html. Again, thank you both for the help!