# how to open app from file manager and play video directly?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make a video player app. I can play video by opening my app manually. But I want to show my app as an option like below picture:
[image]

in short, when I click any video file in file manager, this will show my app as an option for playing that video. When user click on my app this will open a particular activity and start playing that file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to inside activity(that you want to open) inside manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

use below code to your activity to get the uri of your file. I have tested the path in `exoplayer`.

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

add intent filter to activity.
very similar to this.

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

also see this [Forcing an app chooser](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ForceChooser)

Comment: when I add your code to an activity. it showing `Missing URL`

Comment: its working but showing red error. activity is opening but `the activity is playing the first file from the list` not that file that I click in file manager.

Comment: `<activity`
            `android:name=".ui.main.exoPlayerTesting"`
            `android:configChanges="screenSize|screenLayout|orientation"`
            `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`
            `<intent-filter>`
                `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>`
                `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`
                `<data android:mimeType="video/*"/>`
            `</intent-filter>`
        `</activity>`

Comment: however, how can I get the path of the video file that I clicked in file manager?? and how can I detect if my activity is opening from file manager or through app manually?

Comment: use intent to get the uri of the file in the class.

Comment: `Uri uri = getIntent().getData();`
                `File file = new File(uri.getPath());`
                `specialPath = file.getAbsolutePath();`
     this code is giving wrong path(tested in emulator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546101/get-real-path-for-uri-android maybe this might of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Read how to achieve this in official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an intent filter in your manifest.xml. This tells the OS which types of media/ files your app is capable of handling. When you click a video file in file manager, Android issues an *implicit* *intent* . This basically puts out a wanted ad (excuse the analogy) to other apps that the file needs to be handled. When this happens, if your app  has the capability to handle this file/ media type, it will respond. From here, if there is only one capable app, it will be selected for the task. If there are multiple capable apps, all of them will be added to a list, which is then displayed to the user (the list in the image you posted above.)

Comment: can you give me the code of `intent-filter`. I am not getting this

Comment: It is just a bit of markup in your app's manifest.xml file. The manifest is auto-generated when you create an app in Android Studio. It holds application-scope configuration data. In other words, In other words, this is where your app stores settings that it needs to work properly.

Comment: However, how can I get the path of the file that I clicked in file manager?