# How can I make my app as default video player?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-videoview

I am building a video player and I want to make my app to be shown when someone want to play a video, like this :[image]

I searched for that for long time,but no results,any body can help me?

Comment: Add an `<intent-filter>` for your player activity for `ACTION_VIEW`, the `content` scheme, and whatever video MIME types you support. There are many open source video player apps, and you can examine what they have in their manifests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all add intent filter to manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Then to get video URI in you Activity:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502446/how-to-open-app-from-file-manager-and-play-video-directly/64503721)