# How to get the image path from uri on all Android devices

Tags: android

I am trying to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546101/get-real-path-for-uri-android).

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwazc.png)

But it is not working for me.
It crashes when I get the image from camera.
The error is from cursor.getString(index) in getDataColum function.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please update your post: 1) Copy/paste the stack trace and error message, 2) Copy/paste the relevant (Java?) code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). Basically, from android docs:

> FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.

It is a new way to share content. In case of get URI, it works similar. You can use the following example: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics