# get real path from android URI after selecting image from gallery

Tags: android, uri, android-cursor, android-storage

I am ( a beginner android) trying to get the real path (ex: image_name.jpg etc) of Image selected from the gallery by the user.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmapImage;
        try {
              bitmapImage =decodeBitmap(selectedImage );
              photoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoImage);
              photoImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
              photoName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.designPhoto);
              File thePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
              photoName.setText(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }


 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {

    String thePath = "no-path-found";
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        thePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return  thePath;
}
```

but I am not getting anything in the `photoName` textView also tried lots of codes and guides but with no sucess.

but when I tried it with

```
photoName.setText(selectedImage.getPath());
```

I am getting

```
/document/image:n (where n=any numbers) ex:/document/image:147
```

but I want a proper file name or path ex: `image_name.jpg` or `/path/image_name.png`

trying it from last 3 hours, it would be great if anyone could help me out. humble Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you assume that it has "real path"? Why don't you use `MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME`?

Comment: because I am new to android coding, after wasting 3 hours I though I must ask question at SO where and why I am doing wrong

Comment: @Selvin Sir thanks a lot `MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` works like charm...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working using

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
```

updated and working code might help others:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {

    String thePath = "no-path-found";
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        thePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return  thePath;
}
```