# Android: Incorrect File name for selected file(From file chooser)

Tags: java, android, file, filechooser

I have a screen where on a button click I open a file chooser and then I select a file named "Test.jpg" for further operation.
I use following code to get name of that file.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
String fileName = file.getName();
```

Here are the results from debugger

```
file.getName() => 167522

file.toString() => /external/images/media/167522
```

I want to get Test.jpg as my filename.
Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: try this you will get full file path and name https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520090/1548824

Comment: which file chooser you are using?

Comment: I am using android intent chooser

Comment: @AkhileshPatil the getPath method mentioned in the link gives null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need path from your uri. here is a method to get path from uri.

```
public  String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    }
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

### Get file name

```
try{
  //call the getPath uri with context and uri
  //To get path from uri
  String path = getPath(this, uri);
  File file = new File(path);
  String filename = file.getName();
  Log.e(TAG, "File Name: " + filename);
}catch(Exception e){
   e("Err", e.toString()+"");
}
```

### output

```
uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A12876
FileName : profile.png
```

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me in Kotlin:

```
private fun getFilename(uri: Uri): String? {
    val cursor = activity?.contentResolver?.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
    var filename: String? = null

    cursor?.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)?.let { nameIndex ->
        cursor.moveToFirst()

        filename = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
        cursor.close()
    }

    return filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```