# Could not be able to get file from uri

Tags: android, uri

I have a simple scenario, I have to select a file from Internal or external storage and upload to a Server using service.

Opening file chooser in this way

```
case R.id.action_cv: {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null), Constant.REQUEST_CODE_OPEN);

    break;
}
```

In `onActivityResult()` I get file

```
if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_OPEN) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri fileUri = data.getData();

        if (Utils.validateFileType(Utils.getMimeType(UserProfileActivity.this, fileUri))){
            Log.e("File", fileUri.toString());
            uploadFile(fileUri.toString());
        } else {
            FutureSmileToast.getInstance()
                    .showToast(getApplicationContext(), "File type is not supported", SuperToast.Background.RED);
        }

    }
}
```

It shows

```
E/File: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/6158-1118%3Asome_file.txt
```

Now the issue is in `uploadFile()` method which is

```
private void uploadFile(String filePath) {

    File file = new File(filePath);

    String fileNameString = System.currentTimeMillis() + file.getName();

    // Parsing any Media type file
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cvfile", fileNameString, requestBody);
    RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

    Call<ServerResponse> call = mRestManager.getApiService().uploadCVFile(fileToUpload, filename);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            if (null != response.body()) {
                serverResponse = response.body();
                if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {

                    //Further proccesing 

                } else {
                    FutureSmileToast.getInstance()
                            .showToast(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), SuperToast.Background.RED);

                }
            } else {
                //
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            FutureSmileToast.getInstance()
                    .showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to upload CV", SuperToast.Background.RED);
        }
    });
} // CV upload
```

This method gives me **Exception**

```
08-11 10:46:35.819 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/6158-1118%3Asome_file.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:166)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:117)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:189)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:129)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-11 10:46:35.823 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-11 10:46:35.824 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-11 10:46:35.824 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
08-11 10:46:35.824 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
08-11 10:46:35.824 27328-27328/pk.futuresmile W/System.err:     ... 14 more
```

How can I get file from URI and resolve the issue which causes exception?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520090/1548824

Comment: before upload file to the server you need to get file path from URI

Comment: @AkhileshPatil yes! and I tried the solution you suggested in comment above it gives me error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/some_file.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: did you provide runtime permission?

Comment: @pskink Sorry could not get, what do you want say?

Comment: Ok wait checking

Comment: I con't figure it out how to call it, a little example please!!

Answer (score 0):

did you check the file path ?? , is it correct ??  , In my case I replaced the file path to **simple path** like `storage/file.txt` then , I directly wrote the path myself and tested and it worked for me (I Did this just for testing to check if it works first) , But yes there is some issue in retrieving file from path nowadays ..

Comment: the path comes from URI

Comment: don't know how to change that!!

Comment: You directly cut and paste the file inside storage like storage/file.txt , then you hardcode your path in your fileUpload method like File file = new File("storage/file.txt"); , I Did this just for testing to check if it  works first ....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `fileProvider` like below:

```
Uri uriName = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "your.app.fileProviderPath",
                        fileName);
```

Comment: How can I set or get `your.app.fileProviderPath`?

Comment: Actually you call your `onActivityResult` through `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` from this case `case R.id.action_cv`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes I see it there! Now what??

Comment: It seems the file path is incorrect or might be malformed. You are getting a `FileNotFoundException`. Could you print this `File file = new File(filePath);` file for me? Log a `file.getAbsolutePath` in your `uploadFile` method