# file path in internal storage is the same on external SD card

Tags: android, android-intent, path, uri, android-sdcard

I am trying to getting absolute file path that selected by user, the result of **"Intent Intent.createChooser"** and setting it in Edittext that name "editTextPath" , I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520090/4205927)
It's working good but the problem it's getting the file path internal storage is the same path in external SD, to relate see this GIF

[image]

the code

```
    class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button browse;
    private Button read;
    private Button clear;
    private EditText editTextPath;
    private TextView text;
    private Intent fileChooserIntent;
    private File file;
    private Uri selectedFile;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_DOC = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
        read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        editTextPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPath);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                    fileChooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                    fileChooserIntent.setType("*/*");
//                    fileChooserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
//                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileChooserIntent, "Select file"), 1);
//                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                browseDocuments();
            }
        });

        read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextPath.getText())) {
                    editTextPath.setError("The file path cannot be empty");
                    return;
                } else {
                    isStoragePermissionGranted();
                }
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText(null);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DOC && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //String Fpath = data.getData().getPath();
            try {
                selectedFile = data.getData();
                file = new File(getFilePath(MainActivity.this, selectedFile));
                editTextPath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(selectedFile);
                Log.i("Type of file", mimeType + "");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    private void readFile() {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
            Log.e("IOException2", e.getCause() + "");
            Log.e("IOException3", "exception", e);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot read this file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                readFile();
                Log.v("Permission is granted", "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("Permission is revoked", "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("", "Permission is granted");
            readFile();
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*public void enableRuntimePermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Log.e("should request", "should request");
            Toast.makeText(this, "I can not read contacts because of permission denied1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.e("request permission", "request permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("Read file", "onRequestPermissionsResult");
                Toast.makeText(this, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                readFile();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private void browseDocuments() {

        String[] mimeTypes =
                {"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                        "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                        "text/plain",
                        "application/pdf"};

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
            if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
            }
        } else {
            String mimeTypesStr = "";
            for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
            }
            intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
        }
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);

    }
}
```

Comment: @commonsware Why duplicate?, the InputStream not solved the issue,  <br/> it's return the path like this /android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream@bdd21c9

Comment: "Why duplicate?" -- quoting my answer there, "there does not have to be a file at all behind the `Uri`, let alone one that you can access". "it's return the path like this /android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream@bdd21c‌​9" -- you appear to be calling `toString()` on an `InputStream`, rather than using Java I/O to copy data from the `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` on a file that you control. Java I/O is covered in any decent book on Java programming.