# How to select a File in Android and calculate its hash(SHA-256)

Tags: android, file, sha

I want to calculate hash(SHA-256) of a file. This File is selected from chooser implemented using Intent. How can I calculate hash of the file whose path is obtained as below.

Intent use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
```

in onActivityResult() I am obtaining the path as below:

```
 if(requestCode == 7){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String Path = data.getData().getPath();
       }
```

I tried various answers provided on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

Comment: "This File is selected from chooser implemented using Intent" -- no, you are selecting a piece of content. It is not necessarily a file. `data.getData().getPath()` will be useless for most values that you get back. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` (`data.getData()` in your code). Pass that stream to a SHA-256 hash algorithm.

Comment: can you please add that in answers with example.

Answer (score -1):

Following code is coming from [How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/41520090)

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.content.ContentUris; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Build; 
import android.os.Environment; 
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * Created by Aki on 1/7/2017.
 */

public class PathUtil {
    /*
     * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        // deal with different Uris.
        if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```