# Getting error (No such file or directory) while uploading file with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am working on android app and I need to post request with file to the server.
I am using `retrofit` to do that and I do `Multipart` api request.
Then I use `Intent.createChooser` to pick the file.

The problem come in when I do `enqueue` to the service call. In the `onFailure` I get this error:

> E/Upload errorrrrrr:: /document/image:77317 (No such file or directory)

However, This is the uri and file path which I get in the `onActivityResult`:

uri: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A77317`

path: `/document/image:77317`

and I put the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
```

### and this is the request:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload_document")
Call<UploadDocuments> uploadDocuments(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part document_name,
        @Part("document_type") RequestBody document_type,
        @Part("fk_id") RequestBody fk_id,
        @Part("type") RequestBody type,
        @Part("certificate_name") RequestBody certificate_name,
        @Part("certificate_description") RequestBody certificate_description,
        @Part("notes") RequestBody notes);
```

How I can solve this problem? 
and Thanks,

### My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_passport);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR );

        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //Display an error
            return;
        }
        else {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            path = data.getData().getPath();
            if(uri != null)
            uploadFile(uri);

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = FileUtils.getFile( fileUri.getPath());

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    final RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("*/*"),
                    file
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    final MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("document_name", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request
    String document_type1 = "CV";
    String fk_id1 ="2";
    String type1 = "property_documents";
    String certificate_name1 = "anyname";
    String certificate_description1 = "anyDesc";
    String notes1 =  "anyNotes";

    RequestBody document_type =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, document_type1);
    RequestBody fk_id =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, fk_id1);
    RequestBody type =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, type1);
    RequestBody certificate_name =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, certificate_name1);
    RequestBody certificate_description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, certificate_description1);
    RequestBody notes =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, notes1);



    // finally, execute the request
    Call<UploadDocuments> call = service.uploadDocuments(
            authorization,body,document_type,
            fk_id,type,certificate_name,
            certificate_description,notes);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadDocuments>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadDocuments> call,Response<UploadDocuments> response) {

            Log.v("Upload", "successssssssssss");
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String status = response.body().getMessage();
                if (status.equals("success")) {
                    String name = response.body().getData().getCertificateName();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done " + name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadDocuments> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload errorrrrrr:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

### Edit:

Also I have additional problem after editing my code as Jeel answer, The problem when I take image capture I get this error:

> E/on getPath: edit profile
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: []
>           at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:340)
>           at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:87)
>           at com.example.android.renteragentapp.API_Utility.FileUtil.getPath(FileUtil.java:65)
>           at com.example.android.renteragentapp.Activity.ScanPassportActivity.uploadFile(ScanPassportActivity.java:195)

```
  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


          if(hasStoragePermission(101)){
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File

                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)) {
                        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ScanPassportActivity.this,
                                "com.example.provider",
                                photoFile);
                        //FAApplication.setPhotoUri(photoURI);
                    } else {
                        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                    }

                    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
                    {
                        takePicture.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        takePicture.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
                    }
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 101);
                }

          }

        }
    });

  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File file = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,   //prefix
            ".jpg",          //suffix
            storageDir       //directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return file;
}
private boolean hasStoragePermission(int requestCode) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);
            return false;
        } else if( checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);

            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

### also I set this provider:

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />

    </provider>
```

Comment: Please check your storage permission.
Have you give permission for storage or not.

Comment: @MehulKabaria yes I put this permission:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: if you are using lollipop or > lollipop device then you have to ask runtime permission.

Comment: are you using android 7 or above

Comment: @MehulKabaria  I use oreo 8.0

Comment: actually its 6 or above , you need run time permissions

Comment: @ManoharReddy where I do that, I am beginner, so can you provide me some code?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Comment: Check my answer @HayaAkkad

Comment: I would recommend using this library for simplicity https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: @ManoharReddy Directly use of library without understanding details about permission module is not good practice.

Comment: What is the code for `FileUtils.getFile()`? @HayaAkkad

Comment: @MehulKabaria Thank you for helping me, but I still having this error!

Comment: @MehulKabaria Handling permission callbacks at 3 places is also not a good way , android needs to improve implementation of runtime permission , till then using a library is better in my opinion . You can still understand whats happening under the hood as the library is open source

Comment: @JeelVankhede it's give me tha same result of this code: File file1 =  new File(fileUri.getPath());  i.e just return the file path

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your issue is that for **API level 19** & above *(Android Kitkat)*, if you open documents provider for your file picker then `Uri` you get back differs depending from where you pick file.

Use this class:

```
public class FileUtil {
    /*
     * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        // deal with different Uris.
        if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                switch (type) {
                    case "image":
                        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        break;
                    case "audio":
                        uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        break;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
                };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("on getPath", "Exception", e);
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

And obtain your file like below:

```
File file = new File(FileUtil.getPath(uri, this)); // *this* here is context, which can be Activity/Fragment
```

**Note:** *Let me know if someone need explanation about code.*

Comment: Provided code hoping that O.P. doesn't have **runtime permission** issue.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, But I get this error when I obtain file: incompatible types required java.io.file found java.lang.string

Comment: Sorry but I have problem when I take capture from the camera, I have this error in Obtain file line (FileUtil.getPath): E/on getPath: edit profile
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: []

Comment: What is your intent for camera capture? Try this intent :  `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` and use this condition for extra (`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
        }`)

Comment: I do that but the problem still, I edit the question with my code. Please can you check? and thanks

Comment: If you provide your created file `Uri` to camera, there should not need to obtain that `Uri` back using `FileUtil` class. you can directly upload that provided file when result from camera arrives.

Comment: Yeees @Jeel I do what you said and now its working completely. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask runtime permission like below before you select image from Gallery.

```
private boolean hasStoragePermission(int requestCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission Granted

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I still having this error!

Comment: I call it in the onActivityResult, like that  if(hasStoragePermission(requestCode)){ ..} That is true? or not?

Comment: and what I pass for requestCode?

Comment: check go to setting > install apps > your apps > permission
Is there storage option is enable or not. its just to check permission is granted or not.

after that you have to access  using 
File file1 = new File(fileUri.getPath()); as jeel answer.

Comment: I check the permission and it is enabled for storage. and I edit the file line as jeel answer. and now its working! <3 thank you very much @Mehul

Comment: this is not a permission issue