# Need absolute file path of selected file using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT in android pie

Tags: android, file, pdf, base64, android-9.0-pie

I want to get pdf and convert it into base64.
use this code to start picker

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            String [] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I had used below solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440869/6864437

but it is not working on android pie

getting below error:
Request header queries do not support projections, selections or sorting

[How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri)

Comment: Why would you need a a File path? You can do all using the obtained url directly.

Comment: For the rest you should post the relevant code.

Comment: String base64 = "";
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length() + 100];
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            int length = new FileInputStream(file).read(buffer);
            base64 = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, 0, length,
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return base64;       use this code to create base 64 and file name is also required to store it in server @blackapps

Comment: Instead of the FileInputSTream you could use an InputStream directly for the obtained uri: `InputSTream is =getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`. The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: @blackapps Also need to retrieve file name and extension

Comment: You can get the DISPLAY_NAME with querying the contentresolver with the obtained uri.

Answer (score 1):

Solution used : I use input stream (suggested by @blackaaps) to get data from file and create new file which I can use to get full path.