# Getting a File path in Android

Tags: android, file, android-studio

I am trying to get a "text/*" file. I am able to get the file path while I am running the following code in an emulator but not while running it on an actual device with the same SDK version.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            String path = data.getData().getPath();
            //String path = uri.getPath();
            path = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1);
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            readsampleData(path);
        }
    }
}
```

And my manifest file contains the necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What is the version of android in the real device? You may need to use FileProvider

Comment: Android 9. API version 28

Comment: The problem is in the getPath() function. to get the path from URI, take a look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/41440869#41440869