# Android Java Get path from URI for an mp4

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a load a mp4 file from the android file browser. However the path from the following code does not work.  It throws an exception

```
        Uri currFileURI = data.getData();
        String path=currFileURI.getPath();

        MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(path);
        } catch( IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Data I have:

data = {Intent@9869} "Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/44 flg=0x1 }"
currFileURI = {Uri$HierarchicalUri@9870} "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/44"
path = "/document/44"

I see this code in stackoverflow:
[How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri/55469368#55469368)

This looks like an overkill

I can see the method takes in a file path.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

So it looks the path from the android file browser is different from what the method wants. I also see that the path from the file browser is different than the file name. Anybody have an insight into what the path should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it looks the path from the android file browser is different from what the method wants

It is not a filesystem path, because a `Uri` is not a file.

> I can see the method takes in a file path

There are many forms of `setDataSource()` on `MediaExtractor`, including [one that takes a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)). Try using that method with your `Uri`.