# Set background image of image button to URI resource in Android?

Tags: android

I have an image button that prompts the user to select a photo from their gallery? How would I change the image of the image button to the photo selected?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the uri to get file path. May refer to [How to get the Full file path from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri)
2. `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)` to get the bitmap.
3. `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)` for your ImageButton