# Why file exists statement not true in android?

Tags: android

I am Working email attachment .I am facing one problem while attachment .Problem Is that i want to sent a mail with attachment .I have one file on this path sdcard0 then fgg then hh.html.When I debug
on this `File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));`
it show   **file:/storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html** 
But After this it not go to if condition why ?

```
File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            uris.add(uri);
                        }
```

Here is my hole code

```
JSONArray attachments = parameters.getJSONArray("attachments");
        if (attachments != null && attachments.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
            for (int i=0; i<attachments.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        uris.add(uri);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error adding an attachment: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
            if (uris.size() > 0) {
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling attachments param: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: What kind of data is there in the attachements array of your JSON? file:/storage/sdcard0/fgg/file.html or things more like /storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html?

Answer (score 1):

Uri to file will need triple slashes :

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html
```

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android).
But i twill probably not work, so try to remove the "file:" part of your string :

```
File file = new File(attachments.getString(i).replace("file:","");
```

Answer (score 1):

in a URI, you have different parts.

First the scheme:

- http://
- file://
- ftp://

Then the path you want to access:

- myfile.txt
- videos/myvideo.avi
- /storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html

So your complete URI should be:

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html
```

More information here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

You can then build your File and check if it exist with this snippet

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("file");
builder.path(myFilePath);
Uri uri = builder.build();
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
if (file.exists()) {
    uris.add(uri);
    // do whatever you want
}
```

EDIT:

If your JSON send you complete URI path, use this code instead:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(attachments.getString(i));
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
if (file.exists()) {
    uris.add(uri);
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try two forward slashes after :

```
file://storage/sdcard0/fgg/hh.html
```

edit:

should be 3 forward slashes

Comment: Ah yes, should be 3 forward slashes.