# How to post audio file to server in android

Tags: android, file, audio, filenotfoundexception

I need to post Audio file(picking from Audio/* intent) to server.here i got Uri, but the posting param type is `File`. I Used below code but it shows /directory/.. is not a absolute path and getting `FileNotFoundException`. Any one suggest me..

Code :

```
Uri uri=data.getData();

File f=new File(uri.getPath());
```

Log:

```
09-26 21:20:19.735: I/System.out(920): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/audio:5257: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is a duplicate)

See here:
[Convert file: Uri to File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android)

Don't use Uri::ToString() and use Uri::getPath() instead.

Comment: it shows filenotfound exception i used getPath() see edited code