# File not found error after selecting a file in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, filenotfoundexception

I want to open a .pdf file in my android app.now i can browse the pdf file and after browsing the file I am getting ***File Not Found*** Error when i check the file exist or not. Now after selecting the file my selected file Uri `data.getData()` is like

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/6333-6131:SHIDHIN.pdf`

and the path when i parse using `data.getData().getPath().toString()` is like

`/document/6333-6131:SHIDHIN.pdf` Here is my code. Please Help me.

```
// To Browse the file

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

After selecting file

```
//onActivityResult

public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FILE_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                        String path  = fileUri.getPath().toString();
                        File f = new File(path);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            System.out.println("\n**** Uri :> "+fileUri.toString());
                            System.out.println("\n**** Path :> "+path.toString());
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewPdf.class);
                            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("\n**** File Not Exist :> "+path);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ShowDialog_Ok("Error", "Cannot Open File");
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file is stored in an app's internal cache, android does not allow other apps to access it. So maybe that could be the problem.

Comment: The file is stored in the external directiory.

Comment: You can not just convert uri to absolute path. you need to use `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16511111/891373

Comment: @Froyo that is also not working for me. I am getting an null pointer exception "ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Also, is it necessary to pass absolute file path? Could you pass Uri only? and use it as `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` ?

Comment: Can u show me one Example using context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the answer but a workaround.

```
File file = new File("some_temp_path"); # you can also use app's internal cache to store the file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = 0;
try {
    len = is.read(buffer);
    while (len != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        len = is.read(buffer);
    }

    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

pass this file's absolute path to your activity.

Comment: This is also not working. we are getting Nullpointer error. I think because of the problem with url. when we retrieve the path from the url the file not exist error is getting.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Update the question with logs

Comment: Hay Sorry.. That was my Mistake I didn't change the some_temp_path. Now its working fine.
Thanks Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Case Study.pdf");

        try {
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(objIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File NotFound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: My .pdf file may change. The user can select the file from their own device.