# File not found when using file after selecting it Android

Tags: android, file

similar to this question [File not found error after selecting a file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075095/file-not-found-error-after-selecting-a-file-in-android) , I get a file not found exception after I select a file from SD however the solution in the question provided did not work for me, but also resulted in another file not found exception. Here is my code, and it throws a filenotfoundexception exactly at the indicated line with an arrow

```
private void fileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),0);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                // Get the path
                try {
                    File f=new File(uri.getPath());
                    Bitmap mBitmap=null;
                    screenRuntime.getRewriteMachine().addSendFile(f);

                    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd=ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY); <-------------
                    PdfRenderer renderer=new PdfRenderer(pfd);
                    final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();

                    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                        PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

                        // say we render for showing on the screen
                        page.render(mBitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                        // do stuff with the bitmap

                        // close the page
                        page.close();
                    }
                    RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContent);
                    rl.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(content.getResources(),mBitmap));
                    // close the renderer
                    renderer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.wtf("Sent file","Sent file");
                // Get the file instance
                // File file = new File(path);
                // Initiate the upload
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the solution in the link does not work for me? or what I could do to fix this? or what could possibly be going wrong?
Here is a copy of the log

line 110 is ParcelFileDescriptor pfd=ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

```
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕          java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at cmu.edu.screenshare.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:110)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6160)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3877)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
02-16 14:50:22.969  26284-26284/cmu.edu.screenshare W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Thanks!

Comment: @saeed the file chosen isn't an image, I use the pdfRenderer API from API 21 to render a page from a pdf file to a bitmap. That isn't really the issue though, nor is it relevant since my code doesn't even reach there. It crashes on the indicated line.

Comment: @saeed ParcelFileDescriptor pfd=ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: @saeed I thought about that too, but I logged the uri.getPath() result in one of my tests, and it printed the path of the file correctly.

Comment: Your checking device sdk version?

Comment: @saeed yes, the minimum API I support is 21 which matches my requirements.

Comment: uri.getPath() is not currect way  to get path   .. ..check  how to get selected file path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Below code to get path from  selected file

```
 public class SelectedFilePath{




            public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
            {

                //check here to KITKAT or new version
                final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

                // DocumentProvider
                if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

                    // ExternalStorageProvider
                    if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final String type = split[0];

                        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                        }
                    }
                    // DownloadsProvider
                    else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://<span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">downloads</span>/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                    // MediaProvider
                    else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final String type = split[0];

                        Uri contentUri = null;
                        if ("image".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        }

                        final String selection = "_id=?";
                        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                                split[1]
                        };

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                    }
                }
                // MediaStore (and general)
                else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

                    // Return the remote address
                    if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                        return uri.getLastPathSegment();

                    return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
                }
                // File
                else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                    return uri.getPath();
                }

                return null;
            }

            public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                               String[] selectionArgs) {

                Cursor cursor = null;
                final String column = "_data";
                final String[] projection = {
                        column
                };

                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                            null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                        return cursor.getString(index);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
                return null;
            }

            public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }


            public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }


            public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }


            public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
                return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }

    }
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Let me Know your result

Comment: Iam happy to helped you

Comment: Is your URI.parse supposed to be like `class=\"IL_AD\">`  for the class span: `Uri.parse("content://<span id=\"IL_AD1\" class=\"IL_AD\">downloads</span>/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));`

Comment: What if file is from Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

The URI which you are receiving here might not be the file. It may be a content URI.

This type of URIs must be read from `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`.

Try out this code below:

```
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                addedFiles = new ArrayList<Attachment>();
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case ADD_FILE_REQ_CODE:
                            if (data.getData() != null) {
                                Uri uri = data.getData();
                                File newFile = new File(uri.getPath());
                                try {

                                    InputStream ips = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[ips.available()];
                                    ips.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    <<Your logic continues>>
}
}
```