# Photo intent, don't understand the path

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

When I launch a Photo Capture intent, the photo path that is gave to me in return is : `content://media/external/images/media/40209` but when I look in my device, the photo path should have been  something like `[..]/pictures/1456164469539.jpg`

Do you know how to get the second path from the first ?

note I use the method described there [Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) by yanokwa.

Thanks,

-------------------- EDIT

I launch my intent like so :

```
private void launchPhotoIntent() {
    Uri photoUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new ContentValues());
    Log.i("renaud","photoUri : "+mPhotoUri.toString());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.SP,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("test",photoUri.toString()).commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
}
```

and In my Callback :

```
else if(requestCode == PostMessageWindowFragment.ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString("test",null)); // data.getData();
    File file = new File(event.uri.getPath());
    Log.i("PICTEST",""+file.length());
}
```

It logs "0"

Comment: What is the output of  `yourUri.uri.getPath()` ?

Comment: "/external/images/media/40211"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I launch a Photo Capture intent, the photo path that is gave to me in return is : content://media/external/images/media/40209

That is not a path. That is a `Uri`, pointing to content.

> the photo path should have been something like [..]/pictures/1456164469539.jpg

Not necessarily.

First, there are thousands of Android device models and thousands of camera apps (both pre-installed and installed by users), some of which implement `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. What one camera app does will not necessarily match what another camera app does.

Second, if you read [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), you will notice that there is no "photo path that is gave to me in return". If you supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, your photo should be in that location. If you do not, use `getExtra("data")` on the `Intent` passed to `onActivityResult()` to get a thumbnail bitmap. You appear to be assuming that the `Intent` will have a `Uri`, and few camera apps do that.

> Do you know how to get the second path from the first ?

That is not possible in general, as a `Uri` does not have to point to a file, let alone a file that you can access. Use `ContentResovler` to work with `Uri` values, such as `openInputStream()` to read in the content pointed to by a `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answed. After getting this image, I'm uploading it to a server throught a multipart request. I already did it for files, it works well. So I tried to build a file with ```final File file = new File(uri.getPath());``` passing the returned Uri as parameter (it created an empty file). But from what I understand, I should have created a file with a random chosen path, and then fill it throught InputStream ?

Comment: @RenaudFavier: "I should have created a file with a random chosen path" -- if you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and you want a full-size photo, you need to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, supplying in there a `Uri` that points to where you want the full-size photo to be. In practice, a `Uri` pointing to a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) should work fine. Then, you can use a `File` object pointing to that location for your upload.

Comment: Humm that's what I first did, but It didn't work then. I'm working on a nexus 5 with android 6, and red that it doens't work as expected on this device. Do you confirm this ? Anyway I'll explore further more, surely I have been doing something wrong. Thank you for your help. I'll come back later if I'm still stuck and update my question otherwise

Comment: @RenaudFavier: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` relies on third-party camera apps, which can have bugs. Only use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` if taking a photo is not particularly important to you or the user. Otherwise, you will need to integrate with the camera APIs directly.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I used with your suggestions. It's still making an empty file, my camra app is the google default one, I'm a bit surprised it's bugged. I think I'll follow your advice and directly deal with the camera API.

Comment: @RenaudFavier: That library is designed to be an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` replacement. It is still a work in progress, but you are welcome to experiment with it and see how it compares to your needs.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The path you get is the file URI. Try with converting it to path using this [Convert file: Uri to File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android)

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for, I know well how to convert uri to file. But the first thing is not the right uri, this creates me an empty file.

Comment: Unfortunatly, there is a known bug (see the link in my post), that makes the documented way of taking a photo not work on my nexus 5.