# Create new file using uri

Tags: java, android

I want to write file using uri.

```
OutputStream output = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

But it returns error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Missing file for 0E47-495B:Download/8324.jpg.xdec at /storage/external_SD/Download/8324.jpg.xdec
```

If I manually create empty file, OutputStream writes stuff. I need to create empty file programmatically with uri before stream opening.

Comment: Did you provide permission in manifest? and also did you checked Runtime permissions

Comment: Yes, I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>`

Comment: Did you checked RunTime permissions?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This might help you - https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: I use it with Lollipop. There is no runtime permissions.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android

Comment: I already checked this. Main part of answers doesn't work. Other doesn't support external_SD recognition. Please, don't suggest uri to absolute path conversion.

Comment: Please show the value of `uri.getPath()`  and `uri.toString()`. And tell us where you get the uri from. Put all in your post please. You should have started your post with this info.

Comment: getPath() returns null, as mentioned in comments (link above).

Comment: I see no null and i do not follow links. Please give all info i asked for. You should really better show what you are doing.

Comment: Please, check this code to understand why your method won't work on real Android device. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41520090/6468311 Note that this code doesn't support external SD. But I found already the way to add support of external storages. It's not simple. Question is still opened. Just because interesting.