# Android save image uri in internal storage

Tags: android, uri, android-gallery

lets say I created an intent to pick an image from gallery or any other directory, I should get a uri from onActivityResult(), is it possible to copy the exact uri to a local file (intetnal storage).

```
    onActivityResult(){

     //get image uri
      Uri uri=data.getData();

      //create a file 

      File image_file=new File(path);


      //now how to save uri to image_File???


    }
```

Comment: Use `ContentResolver#openInputStream(Uri)` to get an `InputStream`, and `Context#openFileOutput()` to get a `FileOutputStream` to a file in internal storage.

Comment: not clear what you want? you want to save image or save Uri?

Comment: @MikeM. can you show an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520771

Comment: @AbuYousuf I want to take the uri from where ever it was and save it exactly to another file locally.

Comment: @MikeM. I used the method but can't find any file generated.

Comment: Where are you looking? `openFileOutput()` will create a file in your app's internal storage.

Comment: Find it? Cool. Actually, I'll mark this as a duplicate, since there's a bunch of questions here already with similar answers. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. just had one more question, if the image is copied to another file will it still have all the details like (exif)

Comment: Yep. You're doing a byte-for-byte copy, so it'll be basically the same file, just in a different place.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for all your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to write in file

**Ignore below code**

```
File path = context.getFilesDir();
File file = new File(path, "myfile.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

Uri uri = ....
String uriStr = uri.toString();
try {
  stream.write(uriStr.getBytes());
} finally {
  stream.close();
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092971/1292557)

**Added:**

get `Bitmap` from `Uri`:

```
   public  Bitmap getContactBitmapFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
    try {

        InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    return null;

}
```

Save `Bitmap` to file

```
    public  File saveBitmapIntoSDCardImage(Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(Util.getTempFileReceivedPath(conetext));
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "file_name" + ".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear in the question, but I don't think they're trying to save the URI itself. I'm pretty sure they want the file it points to. At least, that's what the code and its comments seem to indicate.

Comment: yes thats why i asked again in comment but @svi.data replied about saving only uri

Comment: I think they're using URI to mean the actual file.

Comment: @MikeM. because it is a bit hard to get path from uri, I want to copy uri to another file (custom file) to get a reference to it.

Comment: @MikeM. lets say I picked image from gallery I want to save the exact image to another file.

Comment: @AbuYousuf the code doesn't work, but thanks any way for your effort.

Comment: @svi.data Yeah, that's what my suggestion addresses. If you're not getting any Exceptions with that method, then I would think that you're looking in the wrong spot for the saved file.

Comment: @svi.data you want to "save the exact image to another file" ?

Comment: @MikeM. I guess I am looking at the wrong answer in the link, can you please refer to what answer you pointed?

Comment: @AbuYousuf yes thats what I want to do.

Comment: @svi.data In place of the `new FileOutputStream(...)` in that example, you'd use `openFileOutput()`. The file will then be under `data/data/your.package.name/`.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah you are right about the answer, it was a mistake done by me (I was deleting the file after it was created), thanks. If you want to provide an answer so I can accept it.