# How to convert an image uri received from another app to a file?

Tags: android

```
if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type!= null) {
        if(type.contains("image/")) {
            Uri uri =  getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            handleImageData(uri);
        }
    }
```

Actually i need to upload this image to server and i am not able to convert it into file. If you can give a complete code it will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert file: Uri to File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android