# Android 11 + Kotlin: Reading a .zip File

Tags: android, kotlin, zip, android-11

I've got an Android app written in Kotlin targeting framework 30+, so I'm working within the new [Android 11 file access restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). The app needs to be able to open an arbitrary .zip file in the shared storage (chosen interactively by the user) then do stuff with the contents of that .zip file.

I'm getting a URI for the .zip file in what I'm led to understand is the canonical way:

```
    val activity = this
    val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            if(it != null) doStuffWithZip(activity, it)
            ...
        }
    }
    getContent.launch("application/zip")
```

My problem is that the [Java.util.zip.ZipFile class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile) I'm using only knows how to open a .zip file specified by a [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String) or a [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File), and I don't have any easy way to get to either of those from a [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri). (I'm guessing that the ZipFile object needs the actual file rather than some kind of stream because it needs to be able to seek...)

The workaround I'm using at present is to turn the Uri into an [InputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream), copy the contents to a temp file in private storage, and make a ZipFile instance from that:

```
        private suspend fun <T> withZipFromUri(
            context: Context,
            uri: Uri, block: suspend (ZipFile) -> T
        ) : T {
            val file = File(context.filesDir, "tempzip.zip")
            try {
                return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    kotlin.runCatching {
                        context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { input ->
                            if (input == null) throw FileNotFoundException("openInputStream failed")
                            file.outputStream().use { input.copyTo(it) }
                        }
                        ZipFile(file, ZipFile.OPEN_READ).use { block.invoke(it) }
                    }.getOrThrow()
                }
            } finally {
                file.delete()
            }
        }
```

Then, I can use it like this:

```
        suspend fun doStuffWithZip(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
            withZipFromUri(context, uri) { // it: ZipFile
                for (entry in it.entries()) {
                    dbg("entry: ${entry.name}") // or whatever
                }
            }
        }
```

This works, and (in my particular case, where the .zip file in question is never more than a couple MB) is reasonably performant.

But, I tend to regard programming by temporary file as the last refuge of the terminally incompetent, thus I can't escape the feeling that I'm missing a trick here. (Admittedly, I *am* terminally incompetent in the context of Android + Kotlin, but I'd like to learn to not be...)

Any better ideas? Is there a cleaner way to implement this that doesn't involve making an extra copy of the file?

Comment: What about a simple `ZipInputStream` ?

Comment: Basically, read contents of `Uri` into an InputStream, convert it to a ZipInputStream, extract (or whatever) and avoid the temp file.

Comment: Thanks, @Shark. Tried it and it works a treat. Perfect!

Comment: What about converting the Uri to a file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370299/1542667

Comment: Yuri: In the general case, the URI you get back as the result of the GetContent() contract may or may not have a "file" scheme. If it doesn't, there's no way to represent it as a File. (Indeed, in a quick test, in my example I'm getting a content:// URI, and tofile() throws.) I fear that any canonical, future-proof solution needs to work with a stream. Or, I suppose, go through the DocumentProvider stuff...

Comment: A couple of subtle points about my getContent code in the first quoted block: 1) Putting the activity in a variable to use it from the lambda is dumb. This is Kotlin; we have "this@MyActivityName". 2) Depending on what exactly doStuffWithZip() is doing with that context, the activity is probably the wrong context to use. It's more likely that you'd want the application context unless you need the activity specifically (and know for sure you don't end up holding a reference to it beyond its lifetime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying from external source (and risking downvoting to oblivion) and this isn't quite an answer, but too long for a comment

```
public class ZipFileUnZipExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path source = Paths.get("/home/mkyong/zip/test.zip");
        Path target = Paths.get("/home/mkyong/zip/");

        try {

            unzipFolder(source, target);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void unzipFolder(Path source, Path target) throws IOException {
        // Put the InputStream obtained from Uri here instead of the FileInputStream perhaps?
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(source.toFile()))) {

            // list files in zip
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

            while (zipEntry != null) {

                boolean isDirectory = false;
                // example 1.1
                // some zip stored files and folders separately
                // e.g data/
                //     data/folder/
                //     data/folder/file.txt
                if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(File.separator)) {
                    isDirectory = true;
                }

                Path newPath = zipSlipProtect(zipEntry, target);

                if (isDirectory) {
                    Files.createDirectories(newPath);
                } else {

                    // example 1.2
                    // some zip stored file path only, need create parent directories
                    // e.g data/folder/file.txt
                    if (newPath.getParent() != null) {
                        if (Files.notExists(newPath.getParent())) {
                            Files.createDirectories(newPath.getParent());
                        }
                    }

                    // copy files, nio
                    Files.copy(zis, newPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                    // copy files, classic
                    /*try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newPath.toFile())) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    }*/
                }

                zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

            }
            zis.closeEntry();

        }

    }

    // protect zip slip attack
    public static Path zipSlipProtect(ZipEntry zipEntry, Path targetDir)
        throws IOException {

        // test zip slip vulnerability
        // Path targetDirResolved = targetDir.resolve("../../" + zipEntry.getName());

        Path targetDirResolved = targetDir.resolve(zipEntry.getName());

        // make sure normalized file still has targetDir as its prefix
        // else throws exception
        Path normalizePath = targetDirResolved.normalize();
        if (!normalizePath.startsWith(targetDir)) {
            throw new IOException("Bad zip entry: " + zipEntry.getName());
        }

        return normalizePath;
    }

}
```

This apparently works with pre-existing files; however since you already have an InputStream read from the `Uri` - you can adapt this and give it a shot.

EDIT:
It seems like it's extracting to `File`s as well - you *could* store the individual ByteArrays somewhere then decide what to do with them later on. But I hope you get the general idea - you can do all of this in-memory, without having to use the disk (temp files or files) in between.

Your requirement is a bit vague and unclear however, so I don't know what you're trying to do, merely suggesting a venue/approach to try out

Answer (score 2):

> > What about a simple ZipInputStream ? –
> > Shark

Good idea @Shark.

```
InputSteam is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
```

Comment: thanks :) i like to think i'm good at what i do.

Answer (score 2):

@Shark has it with [ZipInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream). I'm not sure how I missed that to begin with, but I sure did.

My `withZipFromUri()` method is much simpler and nicer now:

```
suspend fun <T> withZipFromUri(
    context: Context,
    uri: Uri, block: suspend (ZipInputStream) -> T
) : T =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        kotlin.runCatching {
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { input ->
                if (input == null) throw FileNotFoundException("openInputStream failed")
                ZipInputStream(input).use {
                    block.invoke(it)
                }
            }
        }.getOrThrow()
    }
```

This isn't call-compatible with the old one (since the block function now takes a `ZipInputStream` as a parameter rather than a `ZipFile`). In my particular case -- and really, in any case where the consumer doesn't mind dealing with entries in the order they appear -- that's OK.

Comment: I'm full of good ideas when not crunched by deadlines :D

Answer (score 0):

Okio (3-Alpha) has a ZipFileSystem https://github.com/square/okio/blob/master/okio/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okio/ZipFileSystem.kt

You could probably combine it with a custom FileSystem that reads the content of that file.  It will require a fair bit of code but will be efficient.

This is an example of a custom filesystem https://github.com/square/okio/blob/88fa50645946bc42725d2f33e143628e7892be1b/okio/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okio/internal/ResourceFileSystem.kt

But I suspect it's simpler to convert the URI to a file and avoid any copying or additional code.

Comment: Every File has a URI, but not every URI refers to a File. URIs can point to lots of resources that don't correspond to files in the filesystem.

Comment: The Okio filesystem could work well.  And Android Uri based filesystem could even be a nice contribution to okio. It's likely to be the optimal solution here, avoiding copies and allowing you to navigate around the zip file efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to check the `.zip` and `.rar` files in the Android-Kotlin FileAdapter(work with file manager), add the bellow function to your code:

```
private fun isZip(name: String): Boolean {
        return name.contains(".zip") || name.contains(".rar")
    }
```