# Open file on Android with QML (Qt.openUrlExternally())

Tags: android, qt, file, pdf, qml

I want to open a file (*.xls*, *.pdf*, *.png*, etc.) using **QML** on *Android* (if *iOS* works even better).

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
Qt.openUrlExternally(url)
/*Qt.openUrlExternally("http://www.example.com)"*/
/*Qt.openUrlExternally("file:///C:/Users/Hello/Pictures/Qt.jpg")*/
```

Both the *Internet URL* and the *Local URL* open perfectly on *Windows*.
The *Internet URL* works also on *Android*, however **I can't** open a **local** file on *Android*.

This is what I've tried on Android:

```
Qt.openUrlExternally("file:/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test_pdf.pdf")
Qt.openUrlExternally("file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/test_pdf.pdf")
Qt.openUrlExternally(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation) + "/test_pdf.pdf")
Qt.openUrlExternally("content:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/test_pdf.pdf");
```

I know there's a couple questios about this on here but no one answered me and also the example don't show how to open a **local file**.

I have *Storage* permission BTW and the file it's there for sure.

***edit:*** if I pick the file through *QMLs fileDilog* this is the *URL* I get: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments/%2F20BLOQUES.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after fighting with this I got to the next conclusions and clarifications:

1. I can't use *JAVA* or *C++*. All I can use is *QML*. This is a closed software platform called [Velneo](https://velneo.es/) and I only have access to the *QML* side.
2. I can't use **file:///**, it has to be **content:///**. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android).
3. *Android* won't open files from **/storage/emulated/0/Documents/** by just typing that route. The URL has to be formatted like this: **content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2Ftest_pdf.pdf** *(read #2)*.
4. It only works on *Android 11*, it does NOT on *Android 10* for some reason.

I'll accept this as the correct answer simply because in my case it's what I needed, I get to meet my requirements.

Just posting this reply in case anyone, some day, will find themselves in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to restriction by Android OS.

You can disable this restriction by using the following code inside of Java part of your application (it can also be written using C++ by the way):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Build;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
{
    try
    {
        Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
        m.invoke(null);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, it is not recommended by Google and the recommended way to open files is to use `content` scheme. You can read about this in more detail here: https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/12/01/sharing-files-android-ios-qt-app.