# How to Transform correctly an URI into a File in kotlin Android Compose and Post it to Server Using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-jetpack-compose, okhttp

I am trying to post an Image into the server, I manage to get the Image URI and Bitmap and want to transform it into a File so I can post it using Retrofit. but I get this error

```
FileNotFoundException: /document/image:29467: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

That is the Code I am using to get he URI

```
   var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val context = LocalContext.current
val bitmap = remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
imageUri?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
            bitmap.value = MediaStore.Images
                .Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, it)
        } else {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, it)
            bitmap.value = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
        }

    }

            val file = File(imageUri!!.path)
```

and This is how I transform it into a request body in my Viewmodel

```
   val response = serviece.addYourBrand(name,
                image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, file.asRequestBody()),
                categoryIDFormBody).body()
```

and that's my Service Interface

```
   @Multipart
    @POST("brand")
    suspend fun addYourBrand (
        @Part("name") name : RequestBody,
        @Part image : MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("category_id[]") categoryId : RequestBody
    ) : Response<BaseResponse>
```

Comment: You must convert the Uri to a File. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792304/15763443)

Comment: No need trying to get a file path. Retrofit can handle the uri.

Comment: I found the answer in @Nesyou comment. It's here [Convert file: Uri to File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android/68792304#68792304)