# File throwing an exception while getting from Uri

Tags: android, kotlin, file

I have stored the file inside the app storage which file path given below

> content://com.example.baseapp/videos/VID_20230308_095810.mp4

I am loading the file inside the videoView and it is working fine. But when I am trying to get the file using uri.toFile() it is return an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme:
> content://com.example.baseapp/videos/VID_20230308_095810.mp4

help me to get the file from the Uri. Thanks in advance

Comment: try with old answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android