# Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to upload file to PHP server using retrofit

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, okhttp

I want to upload multiple `pdf` files to my server. I am following [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) link for this purpose. My code is as following:

**server_interface.java:**

```
public interface server_interface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("server.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadMultipleFilesDynamic(
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files
    );
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
server_interface api;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Uri uri: list){
        parts.add(prepareFilePart(uri));
    }
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(server_interface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

    api = retrofit.create(server_interface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadcall = api.uploadMultipleFilesDynamic(parts);
    if(uploadcall != null){
        uploadcall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.body() != null) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d("response",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(Uri fileUri) {
    File file = new File(fileUri.toString());
    Log.d("exists", String.valueOf(file.exists())); //shows false
    RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        file
                );
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pdf", file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

**server.php:**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    if(count($_FILES) > 0){
        $location = array();
        $folder="attachments/";
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
            if(!file_exists($folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])){
                $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                if($moved){
                    if($i != count($_FILES['file']['name'])-1)
                        array_push($location,$folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].';');
                    else
                        array_push($location,$folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
                }
                else{
                    array_push($location,"Unable to upload");
                }
           }
           else{
                if($i != count($_FILES['file']['name'])-1)
                    array_push($location,$folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].';');
                else
                    array_push($location,$folder.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
           }
        }
        if(count($location) != 0){
           if(!in_array("Unable to upload",$location))
               echo json_encode($location);
           else
               echo "An attachment wasn't uploaded. Please try again. If issue persists, contact ITC/NFR/MLG";
        }
        else
           echo "Unable to upload";
    }
?>
```

When I execute my code, I keep getting an error in my `onFailure()`:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/document:1000011388: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT:** This is how I am getting the `uri`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> intentresultlauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                if(data != null){
                    Uri pdf_data = data.getData();
                    prepareFilePart(pdf_data);
                }
            }
        }
);
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intentresultlauncher.launch(intent);
});
```

Comment: You use a non existing impossible path. File.exists() would have told you already if you had used it before trying to upload.

Comment: fileUri.getPath() gave you nonsense. Have a look at fileUri.toString() for a nice content scheme.

Comment: Here it says otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370299/21917572

Comment: Yes, but that is irrelevant as it has nothing to do with your use case. And the 'path'  is nonsense as you have seen. And you should have confirmed that File.exists() told you so. React to the point please.

Comment: You're right, `file.exists()` shows false for all the files. But why?

Comment: Repeat: because what you try to do is wrong. You just take a part of the content scheme. If you had seen a few file system paths before you would see immediately that you got an impossible path. You should use the whole content scheme. The whole uri. Uri.toString().

Comment: Yes, I tried `Uri.toString()` it keeps showing false

Comment: Uri.toString() gives you a string. Not true or false.