# How do I get the real path from a URI pointing to a PDF file in android?

Tags: java, android, uri

I want to get the PDF file's real path from it's URI. This is my code:

```
@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(Uri fileUri) {
    File file = new File(getPDFPath(fileUri));
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),file);
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pdf", file.getName(), requestFile);
}

public String getPDFPath(Uri uri){
    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.parseLong(id));
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

This is how I am getting the `uri`:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> intentresultlauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                if(data != null){
                    Uri pdf_data = data.getData();
                    prepareFilePart(pdf_data);
                }
            }
        }
);
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intentresultlauncher.launch(intent);
});
```

Everytime I run the code, I get this error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "document:1000011543"

How do I resolve this error? Where am I going wrong? Or is there any other way of getting the file path?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there is a file path?  There's a reason it uses URIs and not paths-  because there are resources available that aren't files that can also be returned.  It could be a URL to a remote server.  Or it could be a URI that maps to a ContentProvider.  There doesn't need to be a file anywhere. So there may not be a path.

Beyond which-  even if it is a file, you may not have permission to access it as one.  You have permission to access the URI returned.  Not necessarily the file it represents.  So stop thinking in terms of files and think in terms of URIs.

Also, your problem is because you assume  DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) returns a number in string form, and then try to parse it to a number.  It doesn't.  It's returning "document:1000011543" and parsing that as a number returns an error because it isn't a number (although it has a number in it).  You're assuming a lot about how these functions work and all of them are wrong.  I suggest you either read the docs, or ask about how these systems actually work.  Also, if a function is going to return a number, it will just return an int.  It's not going to return it as a string.  That should have been your first cue that you were making a bad assumption

Comment: I want to convert the PDF file to `MultipartBody.Part` object, so that I can upload the file to the server. Can you suggest me a way to do so?

Comment: @abishek_6198 You can try passing in the URI as a string, that may or may not work.  If it doesn't, you'll have to use the 2 value version of the function that takes the name as parameter one and the actual string to send as parameter two.

Comment: @abhishek_6198 You may also in future questions want to include the library you're using.  Multipart HTTP is not part of base Java or Android.  I'm assuming you're using OKHttp (which is used by retrofit if you're using that), but I'm making an educated guess.

Comment: Yes, I am using `retrofit2` for this purpose, this is my actual post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76462226/21917572

Answer (score 0):

> > want to convert the PDF file to MultipartBody.Part object, so that I can upload the file to the server. Can you suggest me a way to do so?

You do not need a file system path to do so.

You can just use the obtained uri for it. That content scheme.

You are number #1234 that comes with this task the last two years

Google for inputstreamrequestbody.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the file's real path from URI using below class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class FileUtilsX {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;

    Context context;

    public FileUtilsX(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public  String getPath( final Uri uri) {
        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider

            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
                if (fullPath != "") {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }


            // DownloadsProvider

            if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    final String id;
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                        }
                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                        };
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            try {
                                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));


                                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
                else {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                }
            }


            // MediaProvider
            if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;

                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};


                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }

            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri);
            }

            if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
            }


            if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

                if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();
                }
                if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                    return getDriveFilePath(uri);
                }
                if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                {

                    // return getFilePathFromURI(context,uri);
                    return copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"userfiles");
                    // return getRealPathFromURI(context,uri);
                }
                else
                {
                    return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
                }

            }
            if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        }
        else {

            if(isWhatsAppFile(uri)){
                return getFilePathForWhatsApp(uri);
            }

            if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                String[] projection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                };
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }




        return null;
    }

    private  boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        return file.exists();
    }

    private String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
        final String type = pathData[0];
        final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
        String fullPath = "";

        // on my Sony devices (4.4.4 & 5.1.1), `type` is a dynamic string
        // something like "71F8-2C0A", some kind of unique id per storage
        // don't know any API that can get the root path of that storage based on its id.
        //
        // so no "primary" type, but let the check here for other devices
        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath;
            }
        }

        // Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() is `true` for external and internal storage
        // so we cannot relay on it.
        //
        // instead, for each possible path, check if file exists
        // we'll start with secondary storage as this could be our (physically) removable sd card
        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
            Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    /***
     * Used for Android Q+
     * @param uri
     * @param newDirName if you want to create a directory, you can set this variable
     * @return
     */
    private String copyFileToInternalStorage(Uri uri,String newDirName) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;

        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, new String[]{
                OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,OpenableColumns.SIZE
        }, null, null, null);


        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         *     * and display it.
         * */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

        File output;
        if(!newDirName.equals("")) {
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name);
        }
        else{
            output = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
        }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            int read = 0;
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        return output.getPath();
    }

    private String getFilePathForWhatsApp(Uri uri){
        return  copyFileToInternalStorage(uri,"whatsapp");
    }

    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public boolean isWhatsAppFile(Uri uri){
        return "com.whatsapp.provider.media".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private  boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


}
```

Use it like this:

```
val realPath = FileUtilsX(this).getPath("PASTE_URI_HERE")
```